# Problema realizando peticiones a una api rest desde angular 5

Tags: angular, api, rest, angular5

tengo una api rest que pruebo desde el postman y obtengo respuesta sin problemas.

```
"content": [
    {
        "username": "john.doe",
        "password": "$2a$10$l1uYkX5AX3pul86A3O5mgujwff6dYDCepixCGwyMjslWP3frCoSpi",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "email": "oscar.toledo@gmail.com",
        "phone": "+53582424",
        "address": "",
        "active": true,
        "fullName": "JohnDoe",
        "blocked": false
    },
    {
        "username": "admin.admin",
        "password": "$2a$10$l1uYkX5AX3pul86A3O5mgujwff6dYDCepixCGwyMjslWP3frCoSpi",
        "firstName": "Admin",
        "lastName": "Admin",
        "email": "oscar.toledo1@gmail.com",
        "phone": "+53582424",
        "address": "",
        "active": true,
        "fullName": "AdminAdmin",
        "blocked": false
    }
],
"last": true,
"totalElements": 2,
```

Esta petición tiene como cabecera un token como parte de la autenticación que tiene implementada. Ahora desde mi app angular consumo el token a la hora de el logeo y no tiene problemas , funciona bien , el problema está cuando intento obtener la lista de los usuarios que debe devolver el json que mostré anteriormente.

Este es el código en angular

Este es el servicio

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders}from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { User } from '../model/user';
import {HttpModule, Http, Response}from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



const cudOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})}

@Injectable()
export class UserServiceService {

  private usersUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8080/pineapple-admin-core/users/list';
  private userUrl: string = 'http://localhost:8080/pineapple-admin-core/users/get';
  private userAdd: string = 'http://localhost:8080/pineapple-admin-core/users/add';
  private userDelete: string = 'http://localhost:8080/pineapple-admin-core/users/delete'; 
  private userUpdate: string = 'http://localhost:8080/pineapple-admin-core/users/update';


  private loginUrl = "http://localhost:8080/pineapple-admin-core/oauth/token"; 


 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
 }

 getUsers(): Observable<User>{
    return this.http.get<User>(this.usersUrl, {headers : new HttpHeaders({'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('userToken')})})
          .catch(this.handleError);
 }  


  getUser(id: string|number): Observable<User>{
   const url = `${this.userUrl}/${id}`;
   return this.http.get<User>(this.userUrl).catch(this.handleError);
  } 


  addUser(user: User): Observable<User>{
    const newUser = Object.assign({}, user);
     return this.http.post<User>(this.userAdd, newUser, cudOptions)
           .catch(this.handleError);
  } 


 deleteUser(user: User|number){
  const id = typeof user === 'number' ? user : user.id;
  const url = `${this.userDelete}/${id}`;
  return this.http.delete(url,cudOptions)
          .catch(this.handleError);
 } 

  updateUser(user : User): Observable<User>{
     return this.http.put(this.userUpdate, user, cudOptions) 
      .catch(this.handleError); 
 }

  userAuthentication(userName: string, password: string){
    var data = "grant_type=password&username="+userName+"&password="+password;

 let headers : HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

   headers = headers.append('Content-Type',  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic b25lbW9yZWNsaWVudGlkOlhZN2ttem9OemwxMDA=');

    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, data, {headers: headers}).catch(this.handleError);
}



  private handleError(error: any){
console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error);
   }


 }
```

Este es el component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../model/user';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserServiceService } from '../../services/user-service.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-crud',
  templateUrl: './user-crud.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-crud.component.css']
})
export class UserCrudComponent implements OnInit {

 private users: any[];

  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
 }

  getUsers() {
     this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((data : any) => {
     console.log(data.content);
    },(err : HttpErrorResponse)=>{
      console.log(err);
   }); 
 }
```

y este es el html

```
<table>

  <thead>
    <tr>
       <td>Columna 1</td>
       <td>Columna 2</td>
       <td>Columna 3</td>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let item of users">
     <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
     <td>{{ item.lastname }}</td>
     <td>{{ item.firstname }}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Necesito poder consumir el servicio y mostrar la lista de usuarios visualmente porque cuando entro en el navegador y cargo la pagina no me muestra nada y en la consola se me imprime el siguiente error.

zone.js:2935 OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/pineapple-admin-core/users/list 401 (No Autorizado)
usercrud:1 Failed to load http://localhost:8080/pineapple-admin-core/users/list: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda de antemano

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es una restricción de seguridad del servidor web. En sí, no se permite que una página web acceda a recursos de otro dominio. Y sí, por el simple hecho de tener puertos diferentes (8080 y 4200) ya se les aplica ésta regla.

Se le conoce como Intercambio de recursos de origen cruzado ( CORS : Cross-origin resource sharing ).

Debes de poder configurar tu servidor web, o sólo tu servicio (pineapple-admin-core) para que acepte peticiones de cualquier dirección o que acepte sólo de la dirección que estás usando en tu cliente (localhost:4200).

Si vas a implementar tu aplicación angular y tu servicio en tu servidor en el mismo puerto, te recomiendo que vuelvas a aplicar la restricción del mismo origen.