# Agregar token a header de web service rest angular6

Tags: webservice, angular6, tokens

Buen día,

Tengo un webservice rest hecho con spring boot que funciona correctamente cuando envió el token por postman pero al enviarlo desde mi front no funciona correctamente, evidencio que el token que envió desde otra aplicación viaja de esta manera

> GET /xxxxx/yyy/v0/commercialmanagement/opportunities/10010999 
>   HTTP/1.1
>   Host: conecta.medplus.net.co:7443
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Accept: */*
>   **Authorization**: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZExvZ2luIjoyNDQ1NywiY2xhdmVWZW50YUFzZXNvciI6IjUzMDQiLCJ1c2VyTmFtZSI6IkNvbmVjdGFNZWRwbHVzIiwiY29kU3VjdXJzYWwiOjEsImNvZERlcGFydGFtZW50byI6MTEwMDEsInN1YiI6IlZJQ1RPUiBXSUxMSUFNIExFT04gUklOQ09OIiwiYXVkIjoiWzE1MF0iLCJleHAiOjE1NDUzMzIwNDMsImlhdCI6MTU0NTMxNzY0M30.YrBba-B3byCVbTrnDC9e-kc5bwCNB6tOBw3XV-URzCE
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
>   Referer: https://conecta.medplus.net.co:7443/conecta_develop/api/swagger-ui.html
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>   Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

Pero al enviarlo desde mi front no sale el campo de autorización aparece en el campo de access-control-request-headers

> OPTIONS /v1/inputParameter/country 
>   HTTP/1.1
>   Host: localhost:9002
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>   Origin: http://localhost:4200
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
>   Accept: */*
>   Referer: http://localhost:4200/crm/commercial/referred/new
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
>   Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8

Mi código angular donde asigno el token es el siguiente

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from 
 '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { System } from 'src/System';

@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    system : System;


    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        this.system = new System();

        req = req.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Accept'       : 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+this.system.getToken(),
          },
        });

        return next.handle(req);
      }
    }
```

Comment: habilitaste las consultas OPTIONS en tu API?

Comment: no, para que es eso?

Comment: mira, [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630231/how-do-cors-and-access-control-allow-headers-work) te explica como solucionarlo.

Comment: Ya le habilite el Option pero el error que me genera es  **Debe proporcionar un token de autorizacion**

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que no coinciden los **headers** del **request** con los del **response**. Debes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Debes agregar los siguientes **headers** a tu response, es decir en tu API

Solo en OPTIONS( como vas a notar, aquí le decimos que debe permitir el header "Autorization"):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
```

Solo en POST:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

En ambos:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain.com:3000`

o para autorizar las consultas desde cualquier origen:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Con esto ya te deberia permitir hacer las consultas. Saludos!