# Obtener contenido de otros sitios web

Tags: javascript

Como obtener el contenido de otro sitio web, es mas quiero obtener el contenido mas su estructura de HTML, obtengo restricciones de politicas de acceso

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>  
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
  function httpGet(theUrl)
  {
    var xmlHttp = null;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
  }
  document.write(httpGet("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/svg/game.htm"));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Esta es la restriccion:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Hay una pregunta parecida a esta pregunta 
 aqui el enlace ([Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)) pero es demasiada general, mientras la que planteo es especifica con un ejemplo que supuestamente deberia funcionar.

Comment: ¿tú problema es con el CORS?

Comment: @dteterevkov si ese mismo

Comment: los get no tienen problemas de cors..

Comment: @gbianchi en ese caso no entiendo porque me sale ese error

Comment: Por curiosidad...el problema es especifico de stackoverflow? Es decir, lo que quieres es obtener datos de stackoverflow, o es simplemente un ejemplo?

Comment: @Pikoh solo es un ejemplo, mejor lo cambio

Comment: Ah ok. Es que precisamente StackOverflow tiene un API disponible, con lo que no tendrías ningun problema.

Comment: @Pikoh necesito obtener el contenido de cualquier pagina

Comment: @Pikoh hace un tiempo lo logre pero con java se, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824460/get-page-content-from-url-in-java

Comment: @PabloLozano encontre este demo http://jsfiddle.net/dLyF2/41/ pero no funciona para todas las paginas

Comment: Eso lo haces rápido en PHP nativo o si tienes tiempo para dedicarle, en Python con Scrapy

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que una página no puede ejecutar una petición a otra página (en otro dominio) por medidas de seguridad. Debes informarte más sobre lo qué es CORS y sus políticas:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Lo que estás intentado hacer no es posible. O más bien, lo que estás intentado hacer se está impidiendo por el servidor de stackoverflow para evitar problemas de seguridad.

Comment: hay otra manera de obtener el contenido de una pagina, con la estructura de su html si es posible?

Comment: Puedes hacer "web scraping", básicamente es recibir en cliente una página y de ella sacar información. Antes de que existiesen las APIs en ciertos servicios, es así como se cogía la información

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente no es posible hacer lo que pides de dominio a dominio, solo es posible si lo haces dentro del mismo dominio. De hecho, hay veces que te va a dar problemas entre un subdominio y el dominio principal.

Para obtener el código de una web fuera de dominio local no vas a poder hacerlo con js o jQuery, porque era un gran problema de seguridad para los administradores de servidores y los servidores mismos. (Un bucle infinito con una petición y podías llegar a tumbar una web). No obstante existen métodos alternativos en PHP con curl(). Si el dominio no tiene ssl puedes hacerlo sin mucho problema en una función bastante sencilla y recoger el resultado por javascript enviándolo desde el PHP. No te pongo el código porque es un desarrollo bastante largo y me pillas trabajando :( pero puedes verlo en esta misma plataforma o en los manuales de PHP: http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php

Espero que te sirva de ayuda y, al menos, facilitarte un camino por donde empezar.

EDITO:

Si buscas en la API de la [Biblioteca Digital del Patrimonio Iberoamericano](http://www.iberoamericadigital.net/BDPI/descargas/API_BDPI.rar) (hecha por un servidor) en el archivo PHP que contiene tienes una conexión y extracción de datos, en este caso de la API de muestre de la BDPI, pero si cambias la url a donde quieras apuntar y quitas la function extracstring puedes conseguir todo lo que necesites de esa web.