# Error CORS leyendo JSON

Tags: ionic3

Desarrollo una app en Ionic 3.20, en la cual leo un archivo json que se encuentra en un servidor. Habiendo instalado la extensión Moesif Origin & CORS Changer, funciona perfecto en Chrome. 
Mi problema comienza cuando hago un **ionic cordova build android**. La apk (copiada al móvil) no lee el archivo json. (La apk, en otras opciones, lee datos correctamente a través de archivos PHP)

Evidentemente hay un error CORS, pero no sé como solucionarlo colocando el header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * en el servidor. La ayuda que solicito es como resolver este inconveniente, y poder leer  archivos JSON, muchas gracias

```
loadData()
{
    let data:Observable<any>;
    data = this.http.get('http://www.blablabla/json/images.json');
    data.subscribe (result => {
      this.images = result;
    })
}
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir una excepción en el Control-Origin del .htaccess:

Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.blablabla/json/images.json"

Comment: Gracias por responder, no sé como es una excepción para este caso. Podría ser algo así que encontré en Internet ?

Comment: <Files "*.json">
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Files>