# Intentando hacer una solicitud a un subdominio funciona con CURL pero no en el navegador

Tags: post, http, cors

Mi dominio en red local http://leboard.com envía una solicitud POST hacia http://api.leboard.com, y causa error de CORS

Cuando uso CURL funciona como espero:

```
curl -X POST -H "Origin: http://leboard.com" -v http://api.leboard.com/login/cookie
```

Da como respuesta:

```
* Trying 192.168.0.125...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.leboard.com (192.168.0.125) port 80 (#0)
> POST /login/cookie HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.leboard.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://leboard.com
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 07 Mar 2019 16:12:46 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Set-Cookie: LSID=56cb7f10df02d6b2d1919f52b0e90780; path=/; domain=api.leboard.com
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self' https://www.google.com https://www.gstatic.com
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.leboard.com left intact
{"status": true, "data": [], error: null}
.
```

Responde correctamente, como esperaría que fuese

Pero cuando hago la solicitud POST desde el navegador, resulta que no se envía POST como debería ser, sino que se envía OPTIONS además de resultar en un error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.leboard.com/login/cookie' from origin 'http://leboard.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
>       .

He probado agregando `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, con `withCredentials: true` y nada.

También he probado con `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://leboard.com` y `withCredentials: true`, y también, nada.

Para todos los casos el mismo error de CORS, mientras que en el CURL funciona perfectamente.

Como puedo hacer solicitudes desde mi dominio a mi subdominio entonces?

*Tengo acceso al servidor donde está mi dominio y subdominio, por si la respuesta requiere modificaciónes. Se usa NGINX.*

Comment: CORS es un protocolo que se aplica sólo a peticiones realizadas por un navegador. Cuando un código javascript (AJAX) intenta un POST a una URL diferente de aquella desde la que se descargó la página que se está mostrando, el navegador en cambio hará una petición OPTIONS a esa URL, y buscará en la respuesta las cabeceras `Access-Control-Allow-...`. Si no están como espera, ya no hará el POST. Esas cabeceras debe incluirlas _el servidor_ y no el cliente. Si el servidor no las incluye, desde el cliente no puedes hacer nada.

Comment: Con curl te funcionará, porque curl no fuerza que se cumplan las restricciones CORS. Es decir, realiza la petición igualmente sin intentar antes OPTIONS. Entre otras cosas porque curl no tiene el concepto de "la página que se está viendo este momento", pero también porque CORS es un mecanismo pensado sólo para navegadores y para evitar el _cross-site scripting_.

Comment: Vale, entiendo. Qué debo hacer en el servidor?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: Mira a ver si te sirve lo que indican aquí https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html