# Envio de cabeceras en Angular

Tags: angular, ionic

tengo un problema al enviar cabeceras en angular
tengo un buscador en la pagina de inicio de esta manera

home.page.html

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="search" (ionChange)="resultadoBusqueda()"></ion-searchbar>
```

en home.page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ServiceApiService } from '../api/service-api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  search: any;
  constructor ( public serviceApiService : ServiceApiService, public loadingController: LoadingController){}

resultadoBusqueda(){
    this.serviceApiService.buscarProductos(this.search).subscribe(
      post=>{
        this.search = post;
        console.log(this.search);
    });
  }
}
```

y tengo un service donde hago las peticiones

service-api.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpInterceptor} from '@angular/common/http';

const apiUrl = "http://localhost/globaltruck/api/";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceApiService {
  constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }

buscarProductos(term){

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'producto': term
    });

    return this.http.post(apiUrl+'busqueda', {}, { headers} );

  }
}
```

cuando pruebo la aplicacion recibo un 404 como se puede ver
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando le quito el " 'producto': term " si recibo una respuesta pero es un JSON de error propio de la Api, que se repite en un bucle infinito, y el value del buscador cambia a "[Object object]" cabe decir que cuando hago la búsqueda desde Postman esta se realiza sin problemas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hay otra manera de enviar cabeceras en angular? gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ProductoService {
    public url: string;
    constructor(private _http: Http) {
        this.url = 'http://backend.com:8000';
    }


    postProducto(term: any) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    /** In Angular 5, including the header Content-Type can invalidate your request */
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('producto', term);
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.post(this.url, {}, options)
        .map(res => res.json()
        .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
        .subscribe(
            data => console.log('success'),
            error => console.log(error)
        ));
    }
}
```

// Actualice mi respuesta para que observes el código completo

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-keeper',
  templateUrl: './keeper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./keeper.component.css'],
  providers: [ProductoService]
})
export class component{

  constructor(private _productoService: ProductoService) {
    Object.assign(this, { single, multi });
   }

   emitirEvento() {
      this._productoervice.postProducto("Producto").subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log(response);
          if (!response) {
            alert('Error con el servidor');
          } else {
            console.log('todo bien');
            alert('Producto dado de alta');
          }
        },
        error => {
            alert('error en la peticion');
        }

      );
    }
}
```

// Aquí un ejemplo breve de mi implementación

Comment: Hola, RequestOptions de donde lo traigo? de '@angular/http' ?

Comment: `
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
`

Disculpa, olvide incluir mis imports, estos son los que utlizó

Comment: Pero en efecto tienes razón, desde esa liberia utilizo ese import

Comment: me marca error en 'options' al ponerlo en el return ...post(.., .., options)

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta, para que veas un ejemplo de mi implementación, si sale un error me gustaría saber el detalle de tu error

Comment: el editor me marca el error aqui return this.http.post(apiUrl+'busqueda', {}, options) en "options"

Comment: Checa el update de mi respuesta, en el código de tu service usas esto:   `constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }``
En mi caso yo utilizo: ` constructor(private _http: Http) {
        this.url = 'http://backend.com:8000';
    }``
Utlizamos "http" de una libreria diferente

Comment: ahora me sale error en ".map"  y "Observable" a pesar q de tengo sus importaciones respectivas

Answer (score 1):

Yo siempre creo un método genérico para este tipo de casos

export class HttpPostService {

private serverUrl = "http://ejemplo.com/apidriver";

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

postData(data: any, route: string) {
    let options = this.createRequestOptions();
    return this.http.post(this.serverUrl + route, data, { headers: options });
}

private createRequestOptions() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    });
    return headers;
}
```

}

Donde route es la otra parte de la api que voy a consultar, y data son los valores que voy a enviar por ejemplo { busqueda : "esto buscare" }