# WebSerivces Angular Error

Tags: angular, webservice, typescript

Buen día para todos, lo que pasa es que estoy consumiendo un servicio de LeagueOfLegends y me sale éste error, no sé porqué me sale.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
De antemano muchas gracias.

[Servicio]

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Post } from '../model/testPost';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestPostService {
post: Post;
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }
  getData() {
    return this.httpClient.get<Post[]>(environment.pruebaMMR, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

[En el componente que quiero que salga]

```
constructor(private dataProfileService: DataProfileService, private testPostService:TestPostService) {
    this.testPostService.getData()
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }
```

La cuestión es que intento consumir un servicio y no he podido

Dejo la URL del servicio para que puedan hacer sus pruebas y sea más fácil ayudarme:
http://www.lolskill.net/summoner/LAN/Dissentient

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error es debido a que intentas obtener datos de un servidor ajeno al que estas manejando, son políticas de seguridad CORS, te puedes saltar estas restricciones usando extensiones en el área te recomiendo esta: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf

la instalas, la activas y listo adiós a esta restricción.

para navegadores basados en chromium funciona bien. si usas firefox busca una similar.

Comment: Pues instalé la extensión que me dices, desaparece el error, pero la cuestión es que devuelve un Null, ¿sabes por qué es?

Comment: Entonces lo más problable que tu variable httpClient no este obteniendo ningún valor, pasa vacía, verifica que estés obteniendo datos, si estas consumiendo consultas de algún .php verifica bien el uso de JSON, usa los JSON.parse(httpClient) o los JSON.stringify(httpClient) (manda alert() para que cheques el contenido) para que puedas realizar conversiones correctamente.

Comment: Pues lo estoy haciendo desde Angular, no meto PHP, pero pues igualmente sigo mirando, porque pensé que no estaba obteniendo nada de la URL, pero la rectifiqué y lo hice con POSTMAN y si funciona perfectamente.