# Error 307 Temporary Redirect en peticion POST con parametro json

Tags: json, ionic, ios, rest, jax-rs

Tengo expuesto un servicio web RESTFul el cual recibe como parametros un Objeto mapeable a `json` y su método es `POST`, El consumo del servicio se realiza desde aplicaciones moviles tanto para android como para iPhone (las aplicaciones se desarrollaron con ionic y se compilaron para android y para iOS), para android el servicio responde de forma satisfactoris, pero para iOS no, retorna un código de respuesta `HTTP 307 Temporary Redirect`

El código del servicios es

```
@POST
@Path("/operacion")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
public Response consultarDatos(SolicitudDatos consulta) {
    IBusiness datosBusiness = new datosBusiness();
    return datosBusiness.consultarDatos(consulta);
}
```

las dependencias del proyecto son:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Se adiciono un filtro para que los `Response` se enviaran con cabeceras.

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter{

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest containerRequest, ContainerResponse containerResponse) {

        ResponseBuilder response = Response.fromResponse(containerResponse.getResponse());
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
        containerResponse.setResponse(response.build());

        return containerResponse;
    }
}
```

Ya he leido he implementado varias soluciones que se encuentran en la red como:

[Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359565/preflight-response-is-not-successful

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998684/cant-send-a-post-request-when-the-content-type-is-set-to-application-json

Sin embargo el error se sigue presentando solo cuando es una aplicación iOS

La configuración es la siguiente

```
iMac
ionic v3.20.0
node v10.15.3
```

La aplicación se sirve en el servidor `node` la cual se despliega en el host `localhost:8100` y se accede a ella desde cualquier navegador.

Ya se realizaron pruebas con firefox y RESTClient hacia el recurso web y estas son exitosas. Pero al realizarlas desde la aplicación servida en el `node` se presenta ese error.

Comment: el error 307 pueden ser otras cosas , te falla solo con la aplicacion de  IOS ? te falla con Postman?

Comment: Prueba desde Postamn, tengo duda de esta linea response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type"); en X-Request-With cambilo por x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Acabo de adicionar la configuración del ambiente de desarrollo.

Comment: @JackNavaRow Si, solo falla con iOS o como he descrito, tambien en el ambiente de desarrollo que lo simula (iMac, node, ionic), se ha probado con exito en Android, SoapUI, Firefox + RESTClient

Comment: intenta probar con https, probablemente los servicios se protegen y te obligan a pasar por https

Comment: @JackNavaRow el recurso web ya es https

Comment: puede ser que la app esta en otra red y por eso no lo veas, mira el log info a ver si esta llegando