# Error al leer un xml por cors en visual studio 2017 con javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, xml, visual-studio-2017, cors

estoy intentando leer un archivo `xml` desde el **visual studio 2017** en **chrome** y me salta éste error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'c://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' from origin
>   'http://localhost:xxxxx' has been blocked by CORS policy.

El código que lo lanza es éste:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", " C:/xxxxxxxxxxx", false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:xxxxx");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

Agradecería ayuda, llevo un tiempo atascado.
He probado usando la extensión de `chrome Allow-Control-Allow-Origin`: * y aún así me salta el error.

Comment: No puedes usar una llamada HTTP para obtener un fichero de sistema de ficheros local, no es sólo un tema de CORS. Además, ese header ha de estar en la respuesta, no en la petición

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas intentando acceder a un fichero local y por razones de seguridad JavaScript bloquea este tipo de accesos. Para permitir esto debes primero servir los directorios o imágenes a las que quieres acceder por ejemplo con un *ngnix* o un *http-server* o incluso con la siguiente extensión de chrome [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb) que funciona a modo de servidor http. En lugar de acceder al directorio *"C:/xxxxxxxxxxx"* harás una petición a donde estes sirviendo tus imágenes (por ejemplo "localhost:8000").