# Solucionar problema CORS en Lumen

Tags: cors, lumen

Estoy montando una API en Lumen a la cual se conecta un front end desarrollado en Angular 8. 
El tema está en que a la que hago una petición `post` me da problemas el CORS. He estado leyendo y he visto a gente que se crea un Middleware para todas las peticiones que devuelve las cabeceras necesarias para que no de problemas el CORS.

Este es mi Middleware:

```
    <?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CorsMiddleware
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
    ];

    if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS'))
    {
        return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
    {
        $response->header($key, $value);
    }

    return $response;
}
}
```

Tengo añadido el Middleware en el fichero `bootstrap/app.php` tal que:

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
     'cors' => App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class
 ]);
```

Y finalmente, en mis rutas lo tengo añadido tal que:

```
$router->group([
    'middleware' => ['cors'], function ($router) {
    $router->post('login', 'AuthenticationController@login');
    $router->delete('logout', 'AuthenticationController@logout');
    $router->post('refresh', 'AuthenticationController@refresh');
    $router->post('me', 'AuthenticationController@me');
});
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/login' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. zone.js:3243 POST http://localhost/login
>
> net::ERR_FAILED

Añado captura de la consola del navegador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que añadir que tengo el Backend (PHP) en un servidor local con MAMP. No sé si esto influye en algo...

No entiendo muy bien qué le falta a mi configuración... alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Juan Sí, estaba bien, se me olvidó quitar el /auth. Perdona. El problema es que si uso Postman, veo como recibe las cabeceras correctas del Middleware, pero usando Angular no me entra ni en el Middleware. Directamente me devuelve un "failed" como código en la parte de Network de la consola del navegador, ni siquiera un error 500.

Comment: Ahí lo mire de nuevo y tenes allow credetinals true junto allow origin `*`. Esas dos cabeceras como están son incompatibles. Cambiá el `*` por `http://localhost:4200` o lo que sea que va en el request como cabecera origin.

Comment: [mira la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/220984/280350), debes configurar tu Apache2

Comment: @Juan si cambio el * por http://localhost:4200 sigue dandome el mismo problema :(

Comment: En el inspect del navegador en el panel de red / network te tiene que salir un item XHR que dice options. Al seleccionarlo podes ver todos los headers. Fijate si podes agregar a la pregunta los headers que estan viajando en el request, incluyendo el de origin. No agregues el valor del de authorization.

Comment: @Juan actualizado! Ahora que me fijo no sale ninguna petición OPTIONS... esto es algo raro, no?

Comment: @Juan no he añadido cabeceras en el POST. Nunca lo he hecho en otras aplicaciones que he desarrollado.

Comment: Si está el POST, poné las del post.

Comment: @Juan no tengo cabeceras en el POST