# Fallo CORS en conexión entre Angular y Java

Tags: angular

Estoy intentando conectar un web Angular a un backend realizado en Java. Para hacer eso hago uso de endpoints, pero me devuelve esto;

> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource.

He modificado **proxy.conf.json** así

```
{
  "/URL/*": {
    "target": "ENDPOINT",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

El **.htaccess**

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Y la configuración de **httpOptions** en angular

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    Authorization: "Token " + localStorage.getItem("token")
  })
```

No funciona.

Entonces: Cual es la forma correcta de corregir ese error?

Comment: Aparecen en el log el registro de las conexiones? si efectivamente está usando el proxy para hacerlas?

Comment: No podes usar el header de Authorization con Access-Control-Allow-Origin `"*"` porque para mandar ese header necesitas la opción "withCredentials:true" y esta opción no es compatible con el origen `"*"`

Comment: Fijate esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin