# error de cors al tratar de hacer una peticion a una API desde Angular

Tags: angular, api, http, cors

estoy tratando de hacer una peticion a una API y estoy obteniendo este error:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response
>   https://LinkDelaApi with MIME type application/json. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

Este error ya lo habia tenido antes en otro proyecto, pero nosotros teniamos el backend y el encargado habilito los cors en el backend y se soluciono. Esta API a la que intento conectarme ahora es una API externa, ellos dicen que eso ya esta habilitado en su servidor, pero sigo teniendo ese problema, que puedo estar haciendo mal?

en mi servicio hago la peticion de esta forma:

esta es la cabecera que envío:

```
 cabecera = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;',
    'Authorization': "",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
  }
```

y esta es la petición:

```
 obtener(){
    return this.http.get<any>('LinkDeLaAPI',{ headers: new HttpHeaders(this.cabecera) });
  }
```

ya deshabilite los cors en el navegador con esto:

```
C:\"Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
```

y tampoco me ayudo. que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: No tengo acceso al servidor para configurar eso que explican ahí.

Comment: Si, ya lo hice, se me olvido mencionarlo y sigo teniendo la misma respuesta,

Comment: que tal si intentas hacer pruebas con [test-cors](https://www.test-cors.org/)

Comment: No es un problema de CORS, es CORB. Es muy similar pero de naturaleza distinta

Comment: Hola @PabloLozano , y como podria solucionarlo? cuando hago la peticion desde postman o colocando el link directamente en el navegador tambien funciona, no entiendo que pasa.

Comment: ¿La URL usa https? Quizá estás usando http y eso no le gusta a Chrome

Comment: estoy usando https

Comment: la direccion que ellos me dan no tiene http ni https, yo le estoy agregando el https.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 1):

Los desarrolladores de Chrome han añadido más seguridad a las peticiones a otros dominios y ahora bloquean lo que consideran datos sospechosos con lo que llaman CORB (Cross-Origin Read Blocking).

- **Si el navegador considera que el *MIME Type* de la respuesta no coincide con el cuerpo de la misma**, o con el tipo de datos que la petición ha declarado que espera, el navegador **bloqueará la lectura** de dicha respuesta, haciendo que el cuerpo tenga 0 bytes.
- **Si la respuesta es de por sí vacía**, es probable que también sea bloqueada, pero puesto que una respuesta bloqueada significa tener un cuerpo vacío, no tendrá efectos sobre tu aplicación, puedes ignorar el warning.

Comment: estuve revisando lo que mencionas, en la documentacion de la API mencionan que retornan un Json y por eyso en la cabecera envio 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' ya no se que mas intentar , llevo horas tratando de resolver esto.

Comment: Comprueba la respuesta en la consola del navegador qué es la respuesta

Comment: en la consola, en la seccion de network/response cuando hago click en la peticion dice:  esta solicitud no tiene datos de respuesta disponibles . y el codigo de status es 200.

Comment: Entonces estamos en el segundo caso que te he expuesto: puedes ignorar el warning porque de todos modos la respuesta era vacía

Comment: Ok, pero la respuesta no deberia ser vacía, es lo que no entiendo. me explico: si yo copio el link de la peticion get y lo pego en el navegador, todo se ejecuta bien y me muestra el resultado, si hago lo mismo en postman o insomnia tambien obtengo la respuesta, el problema esta con angular en como lo estoy haciendo pero no hallo el por que.

Comment: Vale, estoy viendo que en la consola tampoco se ve la respuesta original... Tendrás que preguntar a los responsables si el JSON que te están mandando es correcto, porque tiene pinta que la respuesta no le gusta a Chrome.

Comment: Deberia de ser correcto, por que es una api reconocida, debo ser el unico al que no le funciona. pruebo desde Firefox y es casi lo mismo, de hecho, se hace la peticion Options pero la peticion Get no se llega a hacer.