# Problema con CORS en propio sitio (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin')

Tags: php, javascript, html, cors

Novato total, agradezco su paciencia.
Estoy desarrollando un sitio el cual mediante un script de js llama a un archivo php para realizar modificaciones en mysql. Todo funcionaba bien, pero de pronto dejó de acceder al archivo php señalando un error: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
El archivo php está en el mismo directorio que el archivo que lo llama.
He encontrado información de problemas relacionados con este error al presentarse entre dos sitios distintos, pero ninguno cuando ocurre dentro de una misma web. 
El archivo que llama contiene el siguiente código:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   function jsBorrar(imagen){
   var idImagen = imagen.getAttribute("data-identificador");
   var accion = imagen.getAttribute("data-accion");
   if (accion == "borrar"){
      //Se ejecuta script php para marcar la imagen como inactiva
                
   $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: 'bs/administrador-imagenes-pp.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data:{imagenID: idImagen, accion: "borrar"},
         success:function(respuestaB){
            window.location.reload(true);
         }
       });
    } else {
       //se ejecuta script php para marcar la imagen como principal
                
    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url: 'bs/administrador-imagenes-pp.php',
       dataType: 'json',
       data:{imagenID: idImagen, accion: "principal"},
          success:function(respuesta){
             window.location.reload(true);
          }
       });
                
     }
     $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
     window.location.reload();
     });
  }

</script>
```

Mientras que el "llamado", el siguiente:

```html
<?php
 if(!isset($_SESSION)){
  session_start();
    }
 header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
 require_once("comunes/dbcon.php");
 require_once("comunes/constantes.php");
 if($c_log){
  file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Se ingresó a archivo administrador-imagenes-pp.php\n",FILE_APPEND);
 }
 $id = (int)$_POST['imagenID'];
 $accion = $_POST['accion'];
 if($accion == "principal"){
  if($c_log){
   file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Se realizará proceso de actualización de imagen principal.\n",FILE_APPEND);
  }
  $consulta = "SELECT publicacionTemporal FROM ".$c_im." WHERE idImagen = ".$id;
  if($resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$consulta)){
   if($c_log){
    file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Se realizó con éxito consulta de identificación de publicación temporal en imágenes a partir de id de imagen.\n",FILE_APPEND);
   }
   if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0){
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
    $ptID = $fila['publicacionTemporal'];
    //Conociendo la publicación temporal, se seleccionan todas sus imágenes para marcalas como no principales
    $consulta = "UPDATE ".$c_im." SET imagenPrincipal = 0 WHERE publicacionTemporal = ".$ptID;
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$consulta)){
     if($c_log){
      file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Se realizó con éxito consulta de actualización para marcar como no principales todas las imágenes de la publicación.\n",FILE_APPEND);
     }
    } else {
     if($c_log){
      file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Error al efectuar consulta de actualización para marcar como no principales todas las imágenes de la publicación:\n     ".mysqli_error($conn)."\n",FILE_APPEND);
     }
    }
    //Se actualiza imagen específica a imagen principal
    $consulta = "UPDATE ".$c_im." SET imagenPrincipal = 1 WHERE idImagen = ".$id;
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $consulta)){
     if($c_log){
      file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Se realizó con éxito consulta de actualización de imagen principal.\n",FILE_APPEND);
     }
    } else {
     if($c_log){
      file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Error en consulta de actualización de imagen principal:\n     ".mysqli_error($conn)."\n",FILE_APPEND);
     }
    }
    if($c_log){
     file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Fin de proceso de actualización de imagen principal.\n",FILE_APPEND);
    }
   } else {
    if($c_log){
     file_put_contents($c_logFile, "La consuta está vacía: evento inesperado.\n",FILE_APPEND);
    }
   }
  } else {
   if($c_log){
    file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Error en consulta de identificación de publicación temporal en imágenes a partir de id de imagen:\n     ".mysqli_error($conn)."\n",FILE_APPEND);
   }
  }
  
 } elseif ($accion == "borrar"){
  if($c_log){
   file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Se realizará proceso de eliminación de imagen.\n",FILE_APPEND);
  }
  //Se indaga la publicación temporal
  $consulta="SELECT publicacionTemporal FROM ".$c_im." WHERE idImagen = ".$id;
  if($resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$consulta)){
   if($c_log){
    file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Se realizó con éxito consulta de imagen a desactivar de publicación temporal.\n";FILE_APPEND);
   } 
   if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0){
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
    $ptID=$fila['publicacionTemporal'];
    //Se deshabilita la imagen, utilizando su identificador
    $consulta = "UPDATE ".$c_im." SET estado = 2 WHERE idImagen = ".$id;
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$consulta)){
     if($c_log){
      file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Se realizó con éxito consulta de actualización para deshabilitar imagen.\n",FILE_APPEND);
     }
    } else {
     if($c_log){
      file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Error al efectuar consulta de actualización para deshabilitar imagen:\n     ".mysqli_error($conn)."\n",FILE_APPEND);
     }
    }
    //Verificar si existe imagen principal activa usando la publicación temporal
    $numImagenes=0;
    $consulta="SELECT idImagen FROM ".$c_im." WHERE imagenPrincipal = 1 AND estado = 1 AND publicacionTemporal = ".$ptID;
    if($resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$consulta)){
     if($c_log){
      file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Se realizó con éxito consulta de búsqueda de imagen principal en publicación temporal.\n",FILE_APPEND);
     }
     $numImagenes = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
     if($numImagenes > 1){
     //Ya hay una imagen principal activa
     } else {
      //No hay imagen principal activa. Verificar si existen otras imágenes activas en la publicación temporal
      $consulta = "SELECT idImagen FROM ".$c_im." WHERE estado = 1 AND publicacionTemporal = ".$ptID;
      if ($resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$consulta))
      {
       //Sí hay imágenes activas. Marcar la primera como principal
       if($c_log){
        file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Se realizó con éxito consuta de imágenes activas en la publicación.\n",FILE_APPEND);
       }
       $fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
       $imagen=(int)$fila['idImagen'];
       $consulta="UPDATE bp1408_imagenes SET imagenPrincipal = 1 WHERE idImagen = ".$imagen;
       mysqli_query($conn,$consulta);
      } else {
       if($c_log){
        file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Error al consultar imágenes activas de la publicación:\n     ".mysqli_error($conn)."\n",FILE_APPEND);
       }
      }
     }
    } else {
     //No hay imagen principal activa. Verificar si existen otras imágenes activas en la publicación temporal
     if($c_log){
      file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Error al efectuar consulta de búsqueda de imagen principal en publicación temporal:\n     ".mysqli_error($conn)."\n",FILE_APPEND);
     }
     $consulta = "SELECT idImagen FROM bp1408_imagenes WHERE estado = 1 AND publicacionTemporal = ".$ptID;
     if ($resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$consulta))
     {
      //Sí hay imágenes activas. Marcar la primera como principal
      $fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
      $imagen=(int)$fila['idImagen'];
      $consulta="UPDATE bp1408_imagenes SET imagenPrincipal = 1 WHERE idImagen = ".$imagen;
      mysqli_query($conn,$consulta);
     }
    } 
   } else {
    if($c_log){
     file_put_contents($c_logFile, "No se obtuvieron registros en la consulta. Evento inesperado.\n",FILE_APPEND);
    }
   }
  } else {
   if($c_log){
    file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Error de consulta: publicación temporal.\n     ".mysqli_error($conn)."\n",FILE_APPEND);
   }
  } 

  if($c_log){
   file_put_contents($c_logFile, "Fin de administrador de imágenes\n",FILE_APPEND);
  }
 }
?>
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente: (una disculpa por ponerlo en imagen; el error desaparece en fracciones de segundo y tuve que tomarle video para poder leerlo)
[image: Mensaje de error]

Comment: Hola @Giovanni y bienvenido, por favor puedes colocar lo que tienes desarrollado y en que momento te esta generando ese error que estas colocando. Y también te invito a dar un recorrido por el el sitio para que veas como se pregunta. Gracias

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: Gracias, @YoelRodriguez. Ya modifiqué la pregunta para tratar de apegarme más al modo del sitio y para tratar de aclarar la situación.

Comment: Si está en la misma carpeta como dices, no deberías poner esto en la URL: `bs/`

Comment: @A.Cedano Ambos están en bs/. Lo he probado con y sin el bs/ (ya que hay un rewrite en .htaccess) y el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: Es raro, porque los errores de este tipo suelen ocurrir cuando el dominio  del cliente es distinto al del servidor. ¿Podrías agregar el mensaje de error completo a la pregunta pulsando en [edit]  a ver si nos da alguna pista?

Comment: Por favor puedes mostrar los errores de la consola del navegador eso lo puedes obtener con la tecla F12 porque como bien te dice @A. Cedano el error se produce cuando la ruta no es correcta. Gracias

Comment: Otra cosa  rara son tus manejos del `success`. ¿Por qué haces esto: `window.location.reload(true);` Yo probaría a poner un `alert` ahí y comentar las recargas de la página. Me parece una lógica algo extraña, pues Ajax existe precisamente para no recargar la página que llama. Llamar a Ajax para luego recargar la página es incongruente.

Comment: Más cosas raras. El mensaje habla de un archivo `perdi-perro-7.php` ¿? Ese archivo no aparece referenciado en ningún sito del código que nos muestras... ¿? La URL de la request tampoco coincide con el código que nos muestras... ¿? Parece que estás buscando el error en el archivo equivocado.

Comment: Estas usando algún .htacces en tu sistema y el error se te desaparece rápido porque estas recargo la pagina.

Comment: @A.Cedano El archivo mencionado es el archivo que llama. Es el que contiene el script de js cuyo código se anexa arriba.

Comment: El problema que estás teniendo es que el request se hace al servidor con www.dominio.com y estas accediendo desde dominio.com. efectivamente es correcto el error de cross domain. No debes modificar las cabeceras del lado del servidor si no asegurarte que la ruta que se utiliza en todo el sitio esté absoluta y unifique los request de ajax con la dirección desde donde ingresas en el navegador.

Comment: Ok, pero la URL del error no es esta: `bs/administrador-imagenes-pp.php` sino que es `bs/perdi-perro-borrar-imagen.php`  ¿Quizá haces alguna redirección? En cuanto a tus manejos en el `success`, comenta las recargas a la página. Sigo sin entender qué pretendes al hacer eso.

Comment: La respuesta está en la imágen. Hay un problema de CORS entre el subdominio www y el TLD sin.