# ¿Alguien sabe por qué sale este error al comunicar entre scripts JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

He estado haciendo una mini aplicacion de piedra, papel o tijera que se divide en dos que se encuentran en dos archivos html (main.html y options.html). Las partes este proyecto son:

> El "login" y el "juego" en sí

el problema es que intento es conectar cada html con diferentes archivos js pero importar los datos que necesito de un archivo en otro. Mi problema es que quiero exportar unos objetos de un archivo js (main.js) a otro archivo js (box.js) y me dice el siguiente error:

> Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/tecnico/Desktop/Proyectos%20de%20programacion/Piedra,%20Papel%20o%20Tijeras/main.js/main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
>
> GET file:///C:/Users/tecnico/Desktop/Proyectos%20de%20programacion/Piedra,%20Papel%20o%20Tijeras/main.js/main.js net::ERR_FAILED

Si alguien sabe que sucede por favor que me explique que es lo que sucede y por que.

```js
"use strict";
//main.js

//selecting DOM elements

//login page
const firstInput= document.getElementById("input");
const firstPlusButton= document.getElementById("plusButton");
const compButton= document.getElementById("computer");
const playerButton= document.getElementById("player");
const secondInput= document.getElementById("input-two");
const secondPlusButton= document.getElementById("plusButton-two");


export let playerOne= {
    name: loginPlayerOne(),
    turn: true,
    option: "",
    points: 0,
}

export let playerTwo= {
    name: loginPlayerTwo(),
    play: playingPlayer(), 
    turn: false,
    option: "",
    points: 0,
}

export let computer= {
    name: "Computer",
    play:playingComputer(),
    turn: false,
    option: "",
    points: 0,
}

    
function loginPlayerOne(){
    firstPlusButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        playerOne.name= firstInput.value;
        console.log(playerOne.name);
    });
    document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{
        if(event.keyCode===13){
            playerOne.name= firstInput.value;
            console.log(playerOne.name);
        }
    });
}

function loginPlayerTwo(){
    playerButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{ 
        secondPlusButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            playerTwo.name= secondInput.value;
            console.log(playerTwo.name);
        })

        document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{
            if(event.keyCode===13){
                playerTwo.name= secondInput.value;
                console.log(playerTwo.name);
            }
        })

        
       
    })
}


function playingComputer(){
    compButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        console.log("Estas jugando contra la computadora");
        versusComputer();
    })
};

function playingPlayer(){
    playerButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        console.log("Estas jugando contra un jugador");
        versusPlayer();
    })
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css/style.css">
    <title>Rock Paper or Scissors</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="principalContainer" >
        <h1 class="title">Rock Paper or Scissors Game</h1>
        <div class="players">
            <div class="playerOne" id="playerOne"><p class="text-player">Put Your Name Player One</p>
                <input type="text" name="" id="input" placeholder="Put your name here"><i class="plusButton" id="plusButton"><p class="plus">+</p></i>
            </div>
            <div id="oponente" class="oponent">
                <a href="#oponente"><input type="button" id="computer" value=".VS Computer"></a><a href="#playertwo"><input type="button" id="player" value=" .VS Player"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="playertwo" class="playerTwo">
                <p class="text-player-two">Put Your Name Player Two</p>
                <input type="text" name="" id="input-two" placeholder="Put your name here"><i class="plusButton-two" id="plusButton-two"><p class="plus-two">+</p></i>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="playLink">
            <a href="options.html" class="game">Let´s Play Folks!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="module" defer src="../main.js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
"use strict";
import {playerOne,playerTwo,computer} from "./main.js";

//box.js

console.log(computer);
console.log(playerOne);
console.log(playerTwo);


//game DOM elements
const playerName= document.getElementById("playerPoints");
const points= document.getElementById("points");
const enemyName= document.getElementById("enemyPoints");
const turnText= document.getElementById("turnText");
const rock= document.getElementById("rock");
const paper= document.getElementById("paper");
const scissors= document.getElementById("scissors");
const winnerText= document.getElementById("winner");
const menu= document.getElementById("newGame");


function versusPlayer(){

    playerName.innerHTML= playerOne.name;    
        
    if(playerOne.turn===true){
        
        rock.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            console.log("rock")
            playerOne.option= "rock";
            playerOne.turn= false;
            console.log(playerOne.option);
            console.log(playerOne.turn);
        });


        paper.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            playerOne.option= "paper";
            playerOne.turn= false;
            console.log(playerOne.option);
            console.log(playerOne.turn);
        });
    };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css/gameStyle.css">
    <title>Rock Paper or Scissors</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="scoreboard">
            <p class="points" id="points">0:0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="playerPoints" id="playerPoints">
            PlayerName
        </div>
        <div class="enemyPoints" id="enemyPoints">
            Computer
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="turnText" id="turnText">
                Your turn Player 1</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="options">
            <div class="rockContainer">
                <img src="../img/fist.png" alt="rock" class="rock" id="rock">
            </div>
            <div class="paperContainer">
                <img src="../img/hand.png" alt="paper" class="paper" id="paper">
            </div>
            <div class="scissorsContainer">
                <img src="../img/scissors.png" alt="scissors" class="scissors" id="scissors">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="alert">
            <p class="winner" id="winner">Paper cover Rock. You won player one!</p>
            <a href="main.html" class="newGame" id="newGame">Lets go to the menu!</a>
        </div>
        <div class="seeStats">
            <a href="#stats" class="statsButton">See Stadistics</a>
        </div>
        <div id="stats" class="modal" onload="stadistics()">
            <a href="#"><img src="../img/x-mark.png" alt="exit" class="exit"></a>
            <div class="stats">
                <img src="../img/refresh.png" alt="refresh" class="refresh" id="refresh">
                <p class="statsTitle">Stadistics</p>
                <ul class="gameList" id="gameList">
                    <!--<li>
                        <p class="player">Player1</p>
                        <p class="finalScore">0:3</p>
                        <p class="secondPlayer">Player2</p>
                    </li>-->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="../main.js/box.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es la ruta que te muestra

'file:///C:/Users/tecnico/Desktop/Proyectos%20de%20programacion/Piedra,%20Papel%20o%20Tijeras/**main.js/main.js'**

Simplemente tienes mala la ruta

en tu código puedo ver unas rutas así

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css/style.css">
<script type="module" defer src="../main.js/main.js"></script>
```

creo que bastaría solo con el siguiente cambio

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
<script type="module" defer src="../main.js"></script>
```

**ojo** que eso de pasar datos de un html a otro no se hace a través de los archivos js, hay otros métodos como usar localstorage o cache o estados en el backend

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás teniendo es un error de CORS, puedes leer sobre CORS [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercambio_de_recursos_de_origen_cruzado)

Algunos navegadores no permiten importar documentos javascripts trabajando directamente sobre el sistema de archivos, necesitas utilizar un servidor web para servir tu proyecto. si tienes apache instalado coloca tu proyecto dentro de la carpeta de apache y accede mediante localhost, o puedes usar algún otro servidor web. si utilizas npm puedes usar [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).