# Promises angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo el siguiente método

```
$scope.export= function() {     
    var promises = [];
    var result = 0;

    promises.push(TestService.getValue1());
    promises.push(TestService.getValue2());

    $q.all(promises).then(function(res) {
        res.forEach(function(a, index) {
            result = result + a
        })
    });
}
```

Me gustaria llamar a: TestService.getValue3(result); => este método hace muchas cosas y tarda en devolver uan respuesta, he probado lo siguiente:

```
    $q.all(promises).then(function(res) {
        res.forEach(function(a, index, array) {
            result = result + a
            if (index === array.length - 1){ 
                  promises.push(TestService.getValue3(result));
            }
        })
    });
```

Otra forma que he probado

```
    $q.all(promises).then(function(res) {
        res.forEach(function(a, index, array) {
            result = result + a
        })
    }).finally{
        var total = TestService.getValue3(result)
        console.log(total); => aqui me muestra undefined
    };
```

Error en ambos casos:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
```

Si llamo asi a ese metodo funciona, solo que cuando esta dentro de un $q.all tengo ese problema:

```
$scope.export= function() {     
    var promises = [];
    promises.push(TestService.getValue3(100));

    $q.all(promises).then(function(res) {
        res.forEach(function(a, index) {
            console.log(a)
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: No acabo de entender qué problema tienes ¿Funciona el código pero es lento?

Comment: me sale un error y no me devuelve respuesta el TestService.getValue3(result)

Comment: ¿Qué error tienes? Puedes [edit] la pregunta y añadir ese detalle

Comment: acabo de editar mi post, gracias

Comment: Tienes un problema de CORS, te recomiendo leer [por qué pasa eso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin) para solucionarlo

Comment: Perdona puse un error que no era, he editado el post con el error q me da

Comment: Tu problema no es con el promise, sino con CORS. Estas intentando acceder a un servirio fuera de tu dominio y el servidor te lo esta bloqueando.

Comment: pero porque si me deja llamarlo si lo hago fuera de un $q.all, es lo que no entiendo