# Llamar a una Cloud Function regresa un error de CORS

Tags: javascript, xml, cors, google-cloud-platform

Esoy tratando de invocar una Google Cloud Function(GCF) con javasciprt, pero me tira CORS error ya probé de todo. Me leí casi todos las preguntas de este tema en stack y foros. alguien pudo solucionar esto? Esta es mi GCF

```
exports.helloWorld =  (req, res) => {
  res.header('Content-Type','application/json');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  res.send("hola");
};
```

este es mi javascript

```
var createCORSRequest = function(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // Most browsers.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // IE8 & IE9
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
};
var url = 'myurl';
var method = 'POST';
var xhr = createCORSRequest(method, url);

xhr.onload = function(ev) {
  // Success code goes here.
  console.log(ev.target.response);
};
xhr.onerror = function(error) {
  // Error code goes here.
  console.log(error);
};
xhr.send();
```

y este es el error que me tira.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'cloudfunctionurl' from origin 'mywebpageurl' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Traté de usar el CORS module de nodeJS, pero tampoco funciona. Probé usar webhook.site, y a la primera no me funciono hasta que le agregue los headers de CORS. Pero no importa de que forma le agregue los CORS headers a mi GCF, no funciona. Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Hi, this is [es.so]. Please, translate your question to spanish, otherwise it will be closed. Hola, esto es [es.so], por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano, de lo contrario terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin/220984#220984

Comment: no me ayuda ese link

Answer (score 0):

lo que pasa es que el Javascript que llama a la Google Cloud Function(GCF) cuando hace la llamada a la GCF como esta está en otro dominio debe de tener los headers de CORS.

Esto lo que significa es que hay que agregar los headers de CORS en la llamada que haces desde tu Javascript.

Es decir que cuando estás creando tu CORS request tienes que añadirle estas dos líneas:

```
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
```