# Access to fetch at from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

hola estoy tratando de subir un video a giphy mediante la api pero siempre obtengo estos errores, alguien sabe que significan:

> mis_guifos.html:1 Access to fetch at 'http://upload.giphy.com/v1/gifs/?&api_key=x58Cq33OnTiwdQ7gRoG1bsCNVFJdEX1d' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
>
> mis_guifos.js:245 POST http://upload.giphy.com/v1/gifs/?&api_key=x58Cq33OnTiwdQ7gRoG1bsCNVFJdEX1d net::ERR_FAILED
>
> mis_guifos.js:248 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Éste es mi código (no sé si la cabecera está bien escrita):

```js
form = new FormData();

form.append('file', recorder.getBlob(), 'myGif.gif');
file = form.get('file');

btn_upload_gif.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var new_header = new Headers();
  var options = {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    headers: new_header,
    cache: "default",
    body: file,
    headers: {
      "content-type": "video/ogg"
    }
  }

  async function uploading_gif(url) {
    let gif_file = await fetch(url, options);
    let gif_file_json = await gif_file.json();
    console.log(gif_file_json);
  }

  uploading_gif(`http://upload.giphy.com/v1/gifs/?&api_key=x58Cq33OnTiwdQ7gRoG1bsCNVFJdEX1d`);
});
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: No puedes subir algo mediante fetch, fetch es solo para obtener informacion y en algunos casos puede usarse para subir información plana es decir cualquier cosa que no tenga que ver con archivos.

Comment: Hola si no se usa fetch que se usaría entonces ?

Comment: Los metodos normales (un formulario con input tipo file) sin usar ajax, o la otra opcion que es tener el mismo formulario pero usar ajax, ademas tener en cuenta que los archivos solo pueden ser compartidos por medio de POST y no de GET.

Comment: @Riven, discrepo con respecto a tu afirmación: *No puedes subir algo mediante fetch, fetch es solo para obtener informacion*. Eso no es correcto, si que puedes usar la API [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Body) para hacer todos los tipos de solicitudes HTTP que existen. Yo revisaría el comentario. Saludos.

Comment: Si efectivamente, tienes razon mauricio, estuve mirando y encontré una pregunta en la que se estaban subiendo datos por fetch, al parecer es posible subir datos por fetch, perdonen mi ignorancia.

Answer (score 0):

Trata de cambiar el `mode: "cors"` por `mode: 'no-cors'`.

Quedaría como

```js
btn_upload_gif.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var new_header = new Headers();
  var options = {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers: new_header,
    cache: "default",
    body: file,
    headers: {
      "content-type": "video/ogg"
    }
  }

  async function uploading_gif(url) {
    let gif_file = await fetch(url, options);
    let gif_file_json = await gif_file.json();
    console.log(gif_file_json);
  }

  uploading_gif(`http://upload.giphy.com/v1/gifs/?&api_key=x58Cq33OnTiwdQ7gRoG1bsCNVFJdEX1d`);
});
```

Aunque esto es poco recomendable, y es solo como última opción.