# ¿Como solucionar el problema de los CORS?

Tags: php, html, php7, cors

Tengo el siguiente servicio:
[Regresa un mapa](https://platinum.upchiapas.edu.mx/v2/mapageo/load.php?programa=)

Lo consumo de la siguiente manera:

```
$direccion = API('https://platinum.upchiapas.edu.mx/v2/mapageo/load.php?programa=');
$json = file_get_contents('');
echo  $json;
```

Sin embargo me regresa el siguiente mensaje:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://platinum.upchiapas.edu.mx/siu/servicio/aspirantesCarreraTotalesJSON' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

He Leido que se debe a que se tiene que incluir cabeceras que contengan detalles de la peticion, pero francamente no se como realizarlo.
La idea es que este mapa, se guarde en una variable y luego usarlo.
He usado la siguiente sintaxis, que me funciona bien, el detalle es que no es buena practica hacer esto:

```
<iframe src="https://platinum.upchiapas.edu.mx/v2/mapageo/load.php?programa=" width="400" height="300" type="text/html">
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)