# Access to fetch a '(localhost)' from origin '(localhost)' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

El error completo

> Access to fetch at '(url de facebook)' (redirected from
> 'http://localhost:4000/auth/facebook') from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

Busque solución y me decían que dentro de las cabeceras del servidor(en mi caso node.js) escribiera esto:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

**Aclaro que ya tengo instalada la dependencia cors e inicializado.**

Entiendo para que es, pero mi problema es cuando hago una petición en especifica de facebook de la dependencia passport, desde el mismo servidor me trae los datos. El problema es cuando lo solicito al frontend, esto no ocurre si solicito otra petición distinta, no sé a que se deba.

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import morgan from "morgan";
const app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
}); 

app.use( cors({ origin: "localhost:3000", credentials: true  }) );
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan("tiny"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const passport = require("passport");
require("./src/routes/Facebook")(passport);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

/* Rutas de Passport */
// Ruta para desloguearse
app.get("/logout", function (req, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/");
});
// Ruta para autenticarse con Facebook (enlace de login)
app.get(
  "/auth/facebook",
  passport.authenticate("facebook", { scope: "email" })
);

app.get(
  "/auth/facebook/callback",
  passport.authenticate("facebook", {
    successRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/",
    failureRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/login",
  })
);

app.set("puerto", process.env.PORT || 4000);
app.listen(app.get("puerto"), () => {
  console.log("Listen: " + app.get("puerto"));
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: No, lo que debes hacer es configurar las cabeceras de tu aplicación Node (Express). Una forma muy simple es usar la librería [`CORS`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors). Saludos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: Si tengo instalada y usada, pero sigue igual. Voy a colocar a editar el post y colocar parte del código. El post lo ví pero no soluciona mi problema. Gracias por la ayuda. @MauricioContreras

Comment: Quita el valor del puerto de la configuración de CORS y agrega el protocolo (`http`): `app.use( cors({ origin: "http://localhost", credentials: true  }) );`. Comenta el resultado.

Comment: También lo intenté anteriormente, y nada. @MauricioContreras. Saludos

Comment: En realidad nunca le va a servir a menos que lo publique en internet o que utilize un proxy, porque desde localhost no va a ser posible. Intente con este: node-http-proxy o publique el servidor web y haga la prueba. Y en facebook developer modifique la ip. Los Facebook developers features no se pueden probar en localhost a menos que configure un proxy.

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez Cuando dices que intente con: node-http-proxy te refieres a un dependencia? Saludo.

Comment: @MairaAlejandraQuintero  lo instala con el gestor de paquetes (npm install bla bla....) En esta dirección esta la documentación : https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy