# Como habilitar cors "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

estoy consultando un api mediante Ajax jQuery pero estoy teniendo problemas con el cors ya que me sale esto en consola "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", lo que he leído es que no deja porque estoy accediendo desde otro lado, entonces como podría solucionarlo?. aquí la función.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        type: "get",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })

});
```

Comment: Daniel, CORS se debe habilitar del lado del API para incluir el dominio desde el cual estás haciendo la petición la lista de origenes permitidos.  [Este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/220984/182188) contiene una buena expilcación relacionada

Answer (score 0):

La api que consumes debe aceptar request de tipo OPTIONS y/o tener seteada la config Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS.

Igual habría que ver la arquitectura de red ... por ejemplo muchos ingress te bloquean por defecto esto .. en kong/konga por ejemplo tiene que habilitarlo con un plugin configurable, con apigee puedes configurarlo directamente sobre los endpoints rest

Otra opción sería usar un BFF si está disponible