# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Django static files en AWS S3

Tags: django, aws, djangorestframework, amazon-s3

Tengo los siguientes mensajes de la imagen cuando cargo el sitio de administración de Django, tengo los archivos estáticos ubicados en aws s3, la página se muestra bien, pero sin embargo me muestra los mensajes señalados. Debo configurar algo adicional en mi bucket de aws s3 o en django ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: @MauricioContreras mm si, algo, pero yo mismo contesté mi pregunta con el error que estaba teniendo.Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, tenia que agregar una configuración adicional en mi bucket del S3, dejo el link del tutorial
https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/

Comment: Si bien el link puede llevar a una solución válida, lo ideal es responder colocando el código relevante de la solución, usando un [mcve]. El motivo es que un link externo puede dejar de funcionar, pero el código escrito en la respuesta siempre estará disponible mientras la pregunta y respuesta no sean cerradas. Saludos