# location.replace no funciona tras la carga de XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy tratando que tras una petición XMLHttpRequest a mi servidor en Node.js, cuando tenga la respuesta se realice una redirección a otra página.

Este es mi código en la página HTML con Javascript.

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/login');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token + '&email=' + profile.getEmail());
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200){
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/home';
      }
    }
```

Pero el location.replace, no funciona dentro de la funcion del onreadystatechange, cuando la línea de código la pongo debajo de este           if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){, como está en el bloque mostrado.

Si lo pongo fuera de la función redirige correctamente, pero claro, quiero esperar a que el servidor me confirme la respuesta antes de redirigir.

En el network se aprecia como la petición ha sido bloqueada en firefox y como cancelada en Chrome.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna sugerencia?
Gracias!

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112456/discussion-on-question-by-roberto-gimenez-location-replace-no-funciona-tras-la-c).

Comment: ¿Podrías probar a poner la petición dentro de una función y poner en la primera línea de la misma `preventDefault()`? Otra cosa, ¿tienes alguna regla en el `.htaccess` de la carpeta `home`?

Comment: A reserva de que confirmes la causa del bloqueo (seguramente aparece en la consola), me inclino a pensar que se trata de un problema de [petición de origen cruzado (CORS)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: no tengo .htaccess, dado que el servidor es nodejs. Yo tambien apunto porque es un problema de CORS, pero mi redireccion se realiza sobre localhost y el mismo puerto, por lo que me sorprende el bloqueo.