# La respuesta CORS no tuvo éxito

Tags: python, django, reactjs, fetch, cors

Estoy diseñando una pagina web en react con backend django y uno de los fetch que tengo implementado me tira error con el cors, realize la peticion html por postman y funciono con exito.

la solicitud en react:

```
const crearPublicacion = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const header = new Headers();
    const formdata = new FormData();
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    const token = cookies.get("token");

    header.append("Authorization", "Token " + token);

    formdata.append("contenido", contenido);
    formdata.append("imagen", imagen);
    formdata.append("fecha", new Date());

    const request = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: header,
        body: formdata,
        redirect: 'follow'
    }

    const data = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/publicaciones', request)

    if(data.status === 200){
        console.log("publicacion agregada con exito")
    }
}
```

el formulario en donde estoy capturando los valores para ejecutar la funcion crearPublicacion:

```
<form onSubmit={crearPublicacion}>
    <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={1} sm={1} lg={1} xl={1}></Grid>
        <Grid item xs={11} sm={11} lg={11} xl={11}>
            <InputBase
                className={classes.input}
                placeholder="¿Algo que contar?"
                inputProps={{ 'aria-label': '¿Algo que contar?' }}
                multiline
                onChange={event => setContenido(event.target.value)}
             />

             <img className={classes.img} src={imagen} alt=""/>
         </Grid>
     </Grid>
     <Grid container>
         <Grid item xs={1} sm={1} lg={1} xl={1}>
             <label htmlFor="imageUpload"><Icon className={classes.icono}>image</Icon></label>
             <input className={classes.inputFile} id="imageUpload" type="file" accept="image/png,image/jpeg" onChange={event => setImagen(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]))}/>
         </Grid>
         <Grid item xs={1} sm={1} lg={1} xl={1}>
             <label htmlFor="imageSend"><Icon className={classes.icono}>send</Icon></label>
             <input className={classes.inputFile} id="imageSend" type="submit"/>
          </Grid>
    </Grid>
</form>
```

en django tengo implementada la libreria 'corsheaders' https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers y la clase que se encarga de retornar la respuesta es la siguiente:

```
class PublicacionesAPI(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            publicacion = Publicacion.objects.all()
            serializer = PublicacionSerializer(publicacion, many=True)

            return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
        except:
            return Response(status = 400)

    def post(self, request):
        try:       
            usuario = User.objects.get(username = request.user)
            cuenta = Cuenta.objects.get(usuario=usuario)
            publicacion = Publicacion(usuario=usuario, contenido=request.data['contenido'], fecha=request.data['fecha'], imagen=request.data['imagen'])
            publicacion.save()

            cuenta.publicaciones.add(publicacion)

            serializer = PublicacionSerializer(publicacion)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
        except:
            return Response(status = 400)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un error de CORS está asociado al backend, en DJango debes de habilitar el CORS para que puedas consumirlo desde React.

En POSTMAN funciona, porque tiene una extensión que permite saltar el problema de Cross Domain, pero por defecto Chrome y los navegadores web, chocarán con ese problema.

Para configurar el CORS en PHP usando DJango, mira esta respuesta
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35761088/7834829

Comment: Solo corrijo la parte de "En POSTMAN funciona, porque tiene una extensión". En realidad Postman omite una política conocida como Same Origin Policy, esto es lo que hace que POSTMAN no le de semántica a las cabeceras correspondientes y que simplemente se salte las restricciones que fijan algunos otros programas como los navegadores, los cuales si implementan dicha política.