# Solucionar problema Cors Policy Vue3 + Axios

Tags: javascript, api, axios, cors, vue3

Me estoy desesperando ya con un tema de las **cors policy**. Utilizando una extensión de **chrom**e no hay problema, pero si la quito me salta por todos los lados. He probado a hacer el *deploy* y no soluciona nada.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://catequesisdelbuenpastor.es/?rest_route=/jwt/v1/auth/validate' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-methods is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

El proyecto está hecho en **VUE3 + Axios**.

Este es el [link](https://redil.catequesisdelbuenpastor.es/) en producción.

### Corrección

He conseguido comunicarme con la **API** de `catequesisdelbuenpastor.es`. Sin embargo, no consigo hacerlo con la otra `api.holded.com`. Esta última es pública por lo que no tengo acceso a su configuración.

Adjunto imagen del *debug* de **chrome**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al entrar en la página tengo este error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://catequesisdelbuenpastor.es/wp-json/ws/v1/users/?JWT=null' from origin 'https://redil.catequesisdelbuenpastor.es' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.` He consultado este post https://stackoverflow.com/a/30554385/18473608 y sugieren poner un valor de `Content-Type` que no solicite un preflight. Por ejemplo, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: No me funciona... no acabo de entenderlo porque desde postman sí funciona

Comment: Ok, compara los headers de la petición realizada en Postman y los headers de la petición en navegador (consulta la pestaña Network o Red del navegador). Alguna diferencia habrá.

Comment: nada... sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Entonces, ¿las 2 peticiones envian los mismos headers de petición y reciben los mimos headers de respuesta?

Comment: El clásico _en Postman sí funciona, en el navegador no_. Si bien [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/402412) está relacionada a Django, igual explica _por qué se da este comportamiento_ (leer específicamente el segundo párrafo).

Comment: Tu API tiene configurados los cors para permitir peticiones de tu aplicación frontend?

Comment: He editado la pregunta ya que he hecho unos avances. Gracias!!

Comment: puedes pasar a producción ? hay algunas api que simplemente no puedes probar en  el navegador porque tienen mas seguridad y fuerzan Headers a la hora de hacer el request, por lo general se suele hacer que en tu propio backend consultas las api y envías los datos a tu propia aplicación, ahora si quieres hacerlo desde la misma aplicación tendrás que subir a ambiente producción para probar si te lee o no el api

Comment: Aca hay una grave confusion.. SIEMPRE va a funcionar desde postman, porque postman es una herramienta para PROBAR.. y el navegador no... entonces, si la api tiene restricciones, el navegador las va a mirar para evitar un ataque DDOS... que dice esa api a la que intentas acceder? cual es la documentacion? que dice sobre los request?

Comment: el problema no es con los headers que se envían y reciben... el problema es que el navegador, antes de hacer una petición a otro dominio, manda un request OPTIONS para ver si está autorizado. Y si no, directamente no lo manda. Es el navegador el que decide no hacerlo, no el servidor el que falla. Se puede leer más [acá](https://www.enmilocalfunciona.io/entendiendo-cors-y-aplicando-soluciones/)

Comment: te han hecho muchas preguntas que no respondes @miguelguigar recomendaria cerrar esta publicacion por falta de informacion o comunicacion pero no existe eso en el reporte.

Comment: Muchas gracias por todas vuestras respuestas y disculpad mi ambigüedad. La API es la siguiente: https://developers.holded.com/reference/api-key
Se trata de una webapp de gestión la cual ya usamos habitualmente. Ahora la intentamos integrar en nuestro CRM. Simplemente intento hacer un fetch normal y no lo consigo... Como comentaba, en postman no hay problema por lo que no es un problema de la API, si no del navegador...

Comment: no creo que sea de navegador ... estarias argumentando que todos los navegadores tiene un error en su codigo y en tu sitio por lo que no permite usar las api ...

Comment: yo estoy casi seguro que no estas siguiendo la documentacion de la api holder

Comment: No no, no quiero decir que haya un error en el navegador, sino que algo está faltando en el header... o algo similar. Pero de verdad que en la documentación no indica nada más. He creado esta API key para hacer pruebas: 5f78977ea0bd484e4094df6207ec4103

Comment: Según holded esto debería funcionar:
const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {accept: 'application/json', key: '5f78977ea0bd484e4094df6207ec4103'}
};

fetch('https://api.holded.com/api/invoicing/v1/contacts', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147162/discussion-between-arcanisgk507-and-miguelguigar).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda y por todos los comentarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Solución**

Resulta que la API sólo aceptaba consultas desde el servidor y esto no estaba indicado en la documentación.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).