# Error blocked by CORS policy PHP

Tags: php, cors

estoy teniendo un problema. Estoy haciendo un fetch en javascript, en el cual le paso un jwt por **Authorization Bearer**, y en los headers del PHP que recibo probe agregandole mil cosas y me sigue tirando el mismo error : "**has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**". Lo raro es que cuando pruebo el servicio mediante POSTMAN (version desktop), me funciona perfectamente.  Probé con varias soluciones de distintas personas que tuvieron el mismo error pero no me funcionaron, sin más preambulo les dejo el codigo:

PHP:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, token, Content-Type, cache-control");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') die();
$_POST = parseBodyParams();

function getAuthorizationHeader(){
        $headers = null;
        if (isset($_SERVER['Authorization'])) {
            $headers = trim($_SERVER["Authorization"]);
        }
        else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])) { 
            $headers = trim($_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]);
        } elseif (function_exists('apache_request_headers')) {
            $requestHeaders = apache_request_headers();
            
            $requestHeaders = array_combine(array_map('ucwords', array_keys($requestHeaders)), array_values($requestHeaders));
           
            if (isset($requestHeaders['Authorization'])) {
                $headers = trim($requestHeaders['Authorization']);
            }
        }
        return $headers;
    }

function getBearerToken() {
    $headers = getAuthorizationHeader();
    
    if (!empty($headers)) {
        if (preg_match('/Bearer\s(\S+)/', $headers, $matches)) {
            return $matches[1];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

$jwt = getBearerToken();
```

Parte de la configuración que envio en js :

```
  const settings = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearer}`
            }
```

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que el código se comparte como texto para permitir que otros repliquen tu problema con facilidad

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: @Alfabravo Disculpa, no tuve en cuenta eso. Ahora pruebo en agregarle el .htaccess que recomienda en ese link, ya que el header lo tendría.

Comment: @Alfabravo ahí intente agregando el .htaccess y no me funciono, me sigue tirando el mismo error. También edite la publicación y puse el código directamente

Comment: Por si acaso, la prueba en Postman no tiene relevancia porque las peticiones las envía siempre buscando evitar eso, pero los navegadores hacen enforcing de las políticas de forma estricta.

Comment: @Alfabravo si me imagine que algo de eso pasaba, ya que no me andaba el postman web y si el desktop.

Comment: Por si acaso, procura siempre borrar caché en el navegador donde pruebes después de cambiar configuraciones. Pueden ser ultraeficientes manteniendo lo que tenías antes...

Comment: @Alfabravo lo acabo de hacer y también lo probé por las dudas en multiples navegadores y nada aún .