# Error con el CORS al hacer una petición desde Angular a una API externa

Tags: angular, http, cors

Soy un programador Junior que esta desarrollando una pequeña aplicación que recoge y muestra datos de una API externa mediante Angular (la API es la de riotgames). Para ello he creado un servicio en la parte de Angular que hace una petición get para obtener los datos, donde le paso los headers necesarios para que "funcione" correctamente la petición, pero me salta el error "**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**", cuando el header que en teoría me dice que me falta existe a la hora de hacer la petición. Así es como tengo el servicio que hace la petición:

```
obtenerInfoSummoner(summoner:string):Observable<any>{
    let headers= new HttpHeaders().set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
                                  .set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
                                  .set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET")
                                  .set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                                  .set("X-Riot-Token",this.token)//Token obligatorio para hacer la peticion, sin el no me autoriza el envío de datos
                                  .set('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                                  
    console.log(headers)//Muestro por consola los headers que se van a usar en la petición, se encuentran los que he escrito arriba
    return this.http.get(this.api+"/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/"+summoner,{headers:headers})
}
```

He probado a hacer la petición en el programa POSTMAN y me devuelve los datos correctamente sin problemas, también he probado a desactivar el CORS del navegador (Google Chrome) y me lo sigue bloqueando, pero esta vez con un error distinto: "**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.**". También he visto que, aunque la petición la haga como get, al acceder a la pestaña de network veo que la petición pasa a ser de método OPTIONS, sin saber por qué. Me gustaría saber que es lo que de verdad esta pasando, si es que me falta algo por poner o directamente es un error de la API. Si necesitáis o queréis ver más información (imágenes, más código o cualquier cosa) pedídmelo y la pondré por aquí. Toda ayuda es bien recibida. Muchas gracias.

Comment: *OPTIONS* es una petición (preflight) que envían los navegadores automaticamente para comprobar que el endpoint que vas a llamar acepta la llamada. Tu llamada GET se ejecutaría *después* de que esa llamada reciba el OK

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: El `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` tiene que ser configurado del lado del servidor, si es una API externa será imposible poder realizar el request.

Comment: Prueba quitar todos los headers, excepto el que se refiere al token. Estuve buscando en la documentación pero no he encontrado nada. Puedes ponerla por aquí?.

Comment: Vale, he entendido lo de la petición preflight y lo del header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, pero si es una API pública, ¿como puedo acceder a los datos de esa API? ¿Tengo que hacer las peticiones desde un backend en vez de desde un frontend como Angular? Respecto a la documentación, no he encontrado nada al respecto. Puedo proporcionar el link de la petición, pero no se si podréis acceder a la información si no tenéis una cuenta. Igualmente, dejo la documentación de la petición que estoy tratando de realizar: [enlace](https://developer.riotgames.com/apis#summoner-v4/GET_getBySummonerName)

Comment: Ya esta solucionado amigos. El problema es que esta API en concreto (al igual que la gran mayoría supongo) no acepta peticiones desde el front-end por motivos de seguridad del token. Lo que he hecho ha sido crear un back-end que recoge los datos de la API y después los mando desde el back-end al front-end para mostrarlos. Muchas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda ^.^