# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at carritoCompras.js

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

No tengo casi experiencia trabajando con js y json, por lo que por más que he buscado este error y probado diferentes cosas, no he podido darle solución.
Estoy trabajando en un carrito de compras, los productos los obtengo de una base de datos, en la página donde muestro los productos se ejecuta bien y por cada boton de agregar carrito, tengo su previo evento 'click'. Hasta ahí todo bien, pero resulta que cuando presiono el botón me sale el error

> 'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
> at carritoCompras.js:34'.

He revisado el codigo al derecho y al revés y no encuentro error en sintaxis y me estoy volviendo loco porque cuando accedo a los archivos de forma manual (por url) e ingreso sus respectivos valores, el carrito de compras funciona con normalidad, agrega los productos al carrito, los elimina y los muestra, por ejemplo: si hago esto de forma manual (*https://localhost/paulina/api/carrito/api-carrito.php?action=mostrar*), me muestra el objeto con su respectiva información, pero al hacerlo desde la página me muestra el error.

```
function actualizarCarritoUI(){
    fetch('https://localhost/paulina/api/carrito/api-carrito.php?action=mostrar')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        let tablaCont = document.querySelector('#tabla-carrito');
        let precioTotal = "";
        let html = "";

        data.items.forEach(element => {
            html += `
                <div class='fila'>
                    <div class='imagen'>
                        <img src='${element.ruta}'  />
                    </div>

                    <div class='info'>
                        <input type='hidden' value='${element.id}' />
                        <div class='nombre'>${element.nombre}</div>
                        <div>${element.cantidad} X € ${element.precio}</div>
                        <div>Subtotal: € ${element.subtotal}</div>
                        <div class='botones'><button class='btn-remove'>Quitar 1 del carrito</button>     </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            `;
        });
        precioTotal = `<p class='precioTotal'>Total: € ${data.info.total}</p>`;
        if(data.info.count > 0){
           var verCarrito = `<a href='pagoCarrito.php' class='pago-carrito'>Ver el carrito</a>`;
        }
        tablaCont.innerHTML = html + precioTotal + verCarrito;

        document.cookie = `items=${data.info.count}`;

        let nItemsCarrito = document.getElementById('cont-carrito');

        nItemsCarrito.innerHTML = `(${data.info.count})`;

        document.querySelectorAll('.btn-remove').forEach(boton => {
            boton.addEventListener('click', event => {
                const id = boton.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].value;
                removeItemFromCarrito(id);
            });
        });

    });
}
```

Esta es la función donde me marca el error, tengo los respectivos header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: carritoCompras.js');

Agradezco mucho sus respuestas.

Cabe resaltar que esto me ocurre en firefox y ME, en Chrome funciona todo correcto

Answer (score 0):

Por partes:

- El error de sintaxis no es de tu código, es al procesar el JSON de la respuesta. Lo que se te está devolviendo parece no ser un JSON válido y `response.json()` lanza un error indicando que no puede procesar el texto. Puedes mirar la respuesta en la herramienta de desarrollo del navegador (pulsando F12), en la pestaña de Red, para comprobar qué respuesta estás obteniendo.
- El header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: carritoCompras.js` no tiene sentido. Este header lo añade el servidor a las respuestas para indicar al navegador que tiene acceso, pero el valor de ese header no es un fichero sino el dominio al que se le da acceso. Revisa [lo que es CORS](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin) para más información.

Comment: Vale, he mirado las respuestas de red pero sigo sin entender, cuando hago la solicitud al pulsar el boton "agregar al carrito", cuando se ejecuta la acción add, me retorna el siguiente json: [{"id":5,"cantidad":1}]. Seguidamente ejecuta la acción mostrar y no me retorna respuesta, pero, cuando hago click sobre la respuesta y en otra pagina me muestra el contenido, aparece lo siguiente {"info":{"count":1,"total":"18.00"},"items":[{"id":"4","nombre":"Brook","precio":"18.00","cantidad":1,"ruta":"img\/brook.png","subtotal":"18.00"}]}. Esto en teoría está correcto, es lo que debería aparecer.

Comment: En un princio aparece como una respuesta vacía pero al hacer clic, está la información del json y al escribir la url de la pagína de los productos, se empieza a ejecutar todo correctamente, entonces no entiendo y me estoy volviendo loco con esto