# ¿Por qué no esta redirigiendo a la pagina de mercadopago con node/express?

Tags: nodejs, angular, express

Desde **Angular** le envio los productos a comprar a **node/express**, éste se encarga de enviar esos productos a **mercadopago**. Desde **node/express** en la linea de código
`res.redirect(response.body.init_point);`. deberia abrir la **interfaz/pagina de mercadopago** para que el usuario pueda pagar. Pero desde **Angular** por consola muestra este error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/checkout/v1/redirect?pref_id=blablabla blabla bla'
> (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/checkout') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

Acá el codigo desde node/express:

archivo **server.ts**

```js
import express from 'express'
var multer  = require('multer')
const uuid = require('uuid')
const app = express(); // inicializo express
const cors = require('cors'); // para que el server acepte peticiones de cualquier puerto ej 4200 de Angular
const path = require('path');

// para que acepte peticiones de cualquier puerto ej 4200 de Angular, caso contrario desde Angular va a dar un error de Police cors
app.use(cors());
// middlewares son funciones que procesan y transforman las peticiones entrantes en el servidor
app.use(express.json());
// para que al enviar datos de un formulario los convierta a objeto json
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  next();
});


app.use(mercadopagoRoutes);

app.use(express.static('public')); // Carpeta public la hago de acceso publica. para poder ver las imagenes desde el navegador

// Configuro el puerto. Tomo el puerto del sistema operativo o el 3000
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

// Inicio el servidor
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('usuarios server on port:', app.get('port'));
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to my API');
})
```

Esta es la ruta:

```
router.post('/checkout', checkout);
```

controlador:

```js
// SDK de Mercado Pago
const mercadopago = require("mercadopago");
import {Compramp} from '../compramp';
import { Request, Response } from "express";

mercadopago.configure({
  // el token es el de "produccion" que te da mercadopago, seria el token del vendedor el que recibe la plata.
  access_token:
    "APP_USR-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx",
});

export const checkout = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
): Promise<Response> => {
 
  let compra = [{
    title: '',
    unit_price: 0,
    quantity: 0
  }]

  let items: Compramp[] = [];

  compra = req.body;

  for(let data of compra){
    items.push({
      title: data.title,
      unit_price: parseInt(data.unit_price.toString()),
      quantity: parseInt(data.quantity.toString())
    });
  }

  try {
    // objeto de preferencia
    let preference = {
      items
    }
      mercadopago.preferences
      .create(preference)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.body);
        // redirije a pagina de mercadopago 'https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/checkout/v1/redirect?pref_id=bla bla bla'
        res.redirect(response.body.init_point);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return res.status(500).json("Internal server error");
  }
};
```

Aca desde Angular muestro como le envio los productos a node/express:

```js
sendData() {

    let compra: Compramp[] = [];
    
    for (let book of this.bookList) {
      compra.push({
        title: book.name,
        unit_price: book.price,
        quantity: book.quantity
      });    
    }
  
    this.mercadopagoService.checkout(compra).subscribe(
      res => {
        //console.log(res);
      },
      err => console.error('Error al recibir la data de compra en el servidor. ' + err)
    );
  }
```

El servicio mercadopago.service:

```js
private SERVER = 'http://localhost:3000/checkout';

 checkout(compra: any) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.SERVER}`, compra);
  }
```

Comment: estas haciendo una redireccion debes terner en cuenta el CORS [te invito a leer esta  pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin) con sus respuestas

Comment: gracias por responder, estuve leyendo, soy novato en esto de node/express y no se muy bien como deberia hacer la configuracion en mi codigo publicado.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/220162/28035 esta respuesta te ayudara a entender un poco mas, para solo prueba deja el * en produccion no tiene que estar

Comment: gracias! acabo de agregarle el middleware de la publicacion del link a mi archivo server.ts, pero sigo teniendo el mismo resultado. Ahi en mi publciacion subo mi archivo server.ts

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: gracias, si estuve investigando ese link en donde le habia agregado a mi archivo server.ts las lineas de acontinuacion....pero sigue smostrando el mismo error:

Comment: , agregue la las lineas app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

Comment: @Claudio pero ese es el primer mddleware que debes agregar

Comment: @jackNavaRow perdon, podrias señalarmelo en mi codigo? porque no entiendo  lo que me dices de que es el primer middleware que tengo q agregar..en que parte?