# Tengo un error cuando quiero usar CHECKOUT PRO de la API DE MERCADO PAGO

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, mercadopago

estoy trabado hace mas de 2 meses con este error. Soy novato por lo que si repondes por favor haganlo en terminos muy basicos. Estoy tratando de desarrollar un ecommerce pagando con mercado pago, hice el lado del servidor y el front. El problema es que cuando pongo pagar en el front me deberia habilitar el boton de la pasarella de pago de mercado pagos, lo hace pero aparece y desaparece intermintente constantemente. Me baje un repo que esta igual a mi codigo y no lo hace. esto me genera mucha frustacion porque ya intente preguntar por aca (no me respondieron), se centraron en que hice mal la pregunta), por foros, por youtube, me vi tutoriales, nadie sabe responderme.
En el error que me tira me dice que falta un encabezado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Acabo de leer la pregunta a la que haces referencia y pues, te soy sincero, eres muy problemático (en especial si exactamente ahora ya te incomodaste). Déjate guiar, nadie tiene una esfera de cristal que les da todos los detalles que se requieren para solucionar tu caso. Te ayudo con unas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Adicionalmente, esa "voz" que suena en tu mente al leer los comentarios es reflejo de tu mundo interno, conozco a los usuarios que te quisieron ayudar y créeme, lo están haciendo de corazón (aunque no lo percibas así), te están dando su tiempo.

Comment: Ahora, pasando al código, y habiendo leído tu otra pregunta. Esto se relaciona muchísimo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/437722/822 y según los comentarios, esto se tiene que realizar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/220162/822 . También esta guía podría ser de utilidad: https://dev.to/nicolascastrogarcia/como-integrar-mercado-pago-a-tu-web-34al

Comment: Ya lo intente app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
}); no funciona, deberia empezar todo de nuevo no?

Comment: Lo mas raro es que de la persona que vi el tutorial baje su codigo, y en el de el no hace error del boton y el codigo esta en apariencia igual

Comment: Sí, empieza por leer el primer enlace que te pasé, considera que llevo varios años en el sitio y he visto N preguntas, las que mejor ingredientes tienen (composición de la pregunta en sí) son las que tienen más altos chances de obtener respuesta. Por otro lado, quizás la API de mercado pago ha cambiado y se tenga que realizar algún paso adicional, quizás no funciona en localhost y tengas que subirlo a algún servidor para probar ahí. Saludos.

Comment: @PabloAlejandroAcuña podrias compartir el repo que comentas que usaste?, eso de habilitar y deshabilitar constantemente me suena a que es error de React y de manejo de estados

Comment: Si mira: https://github.com/pab-mchn/MercadoPago_ReactJs

Comment: el video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXe_TxNVOkI&t=650s

Comment: Como veras en su video, el pone BUY y aparece el boton que habilita la pasarella de pagos, yo lo hago y aparece y desaparece constantemente el boton. si logro presionarlo en algun momento, funciona y me habilita la pasarella para abonar con los datos correctos pero obviamente no deberia de estar asi.