# CORS y response opaque?

Tags: javascript, fetch, cors, response

estube trabajando hasta el momento en local, con live server y a traves de una peticion fetch tomaba un html externo e insertaba el contenido dentro de un div en el index.html, esto funcionaba de maravillas con este codigo:

```
fetch("/secciones.html",
).then(response => {
  return console.log(response)
  d.querySelector(".contenedor").innerHTML = response;
}).catch(error => {
  return console.log(error)
});
```

el caso es que subi el archivo (solo el html externo secciones) a un server real, donde estara la pagina para probar la respuesta, el codigo como sigue:

```
fetch("http://www.xxx.com.ar/demo/hernan/secciones.html",
).then(response => {
  return console.log(response)
  d.querySelector(".contenedor").innerHTML = response;
}).catch(error => {
  return console.log(error)
});
```

lo que me dio un error CORS, luego puse esto y si bien el error cors no aparecio otra vez si recibo una response opaque, un error 403, seria algo como que se acepto la peticion pero se niega a mandar el body del response, no encuntro manera de solucionarlo, lo que agregue fue esto:

```
fetch("http://www.xxx.com.ar/demo/hernan/secciones.html",
{mode:"no-cors",
headers:{
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            }
}
).then(response => {
  return console.log(response)
  d.querySelector(".contenedor").innerHTML = response;
}).catch(error => {
  return console.log(error)
});
```

que puede estar pasando??
perdon pero no me permiten pasar la direccion del server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues, si no tienes control del servidor, no puedes habilitar el CORS. Más detalles: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/218426/822

Comment: Si tienes problemas de CORS es porque estás dirigiendo la petición a otro servidor, en ese caso, tendrías que pedir a ese servidor que autorice a tu dominio para poder hacer peticiones a los recursos que éste expone para ser consultados. Ese permiso puede otorgarse de diversos modos... El problema principal ahora mismo es que ni siquiera eso queda claro en tu rpregunta.

Comment: @A. Cedano. Tengo el index en el live server, en local, y el archivo secciones.html en el server y no funciona. O sea estaria peticionando desde un server local a un server real. Pero de ese mismo server estoy peticionando fotos en png y las recibo sin problemas

Comment: Necesitamos ver el mensaje de error completo para poder ayudarte, varias cosas pueden estar ocurriendo, por ejemplo que la carpeta de esa petición en concreto esté protegida, que se restrinja su acceso vía `.htaccess` o de otro modo, que se necesite una contraseña para acceder a ella, etc

Comment: ahi coloque los mensajes de error, el primero es peticionando una foto y da ok