# error de CORS en api jsonplaceholder desde Angular

Tags: angular, api, cors

Desde **Angular** quiero conectarme a la **api jsonplaceholder**, pero sale error de **CORS** ¿Cómo se soluciona esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi servicio:**

```
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(): Observable<any>{
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';
    return this.http.get(url);
  }

}
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-api-placeholder',
  templateUrl: './api-placeholder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./api-placeholder.component.scss']
})

export class ApiPlaceholderComponent implements OnInit {

  data:Array<any>;

  constructor(
    private api: ApiService
  ) { 
    this.data = new Array<any>();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getPhotos();
  }

  getPhotos(){
    this.api.getData().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.data = data;
      },
        err => console.error('api data failed')
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: La web https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ no implementa CORS, por lo que no puedes hacer llamadas ajax desde otro dominio: https://github.com/typicode/jsonplaceholder/issues/159

Comment: gracias por responder!, entonces no hay forma  que desde Angular pueda traer los datos de la api para mostrarlos en la vista?

Comment: Desde Angular o desde cualquier otro framework: las llamadas son canceladas por tu navegador

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: gracias! esa documentación ayudaria a configurar el CORS desde un servidor, yo la api la estoy consumiendo directamente de forma local con angular sin ningun servidor de por medio como node/express.

Comment: Lo imagino, pero ahora ya sabes que si no puedes modificar el servidor al que estás pidiendo los datos, entonces no hay nada que hacer. Si quieres hacer pruebas para consumir un API rest sin este problema, puedes usar https://swapi.dev/, por ejemplo

Comment: El problema está en la ruta que estás usando, no existe. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/ Al final están las rutas válidas.

Comment: @Lobos gracias por responder, cambie la ruta por esta: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/albums tmb utilice esta: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments sin embargo tira el mismo error de CORS