# Retorno vacío de body status 200

Tags: php, mysql, api, apache2, centos7

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente con el consumo de un servicio, al hacer uso del siguiente código  como enrutador a las clases me retorna un status code 200 pero sin retornar información en el cuerpo de la petición.

Al validar la petición desde mi local obtengo una respuesta 200 con un json serializado correctamente, pero al subirlo a mi servidor de CentOS 7 con Apache 2 tengo el error anteriormente descrito.

```
    <?php
    try {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    
        $content = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
        $typeContent = $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'];
    
        if($typeContent != 'application/json'){
            echo json_encode([
                "status" => false,
                "message" => "Tipo de method incorrecto"
            ]);
        }
    
        $type = $content['component'];
        $action = $content['action'];
        $request = $content;
    
        $valid = false;
    
        switch ($type) {
            case 'permissions':
                include_once 'permisos/actions.php';
                $product = new Permit();
                if(method_exists('Permit', $action)){
                    $valid = !$valid;
                    $response = $product->$action($request);
                    echo $response;
                }
                break;
            case 'modules':
                include_once 'modules/actions.php';
                $product = new Module();
                if(method_exists('Module', $action)){
                    $valid = !$valid;
                    $response = $product->$action($request);
                    echo $response;
                }
                break;
            default:
                echo json_encode([
                    "status" => false,
                    "message"=> "Ruta no valida"
                ]);
                break;
        }
    
        if(!$valid){
            echo json_encode([
                "status" => false,
                "message"=> "Ruta no valida"
            ]);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
    }


?>
```

Comment: cuidado con esta linea[header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin) es un error tipico de seguridad

Comment: que tal si validas la version de PHP en el servidor y en tu maquina local,

Comment: En mi máquina local tengo la versión 7.3.1 y en el servidor tengo la versión 7.4.19

Comment: ¿Revisaste el log del servidor? En el header indicas regresar `text/html` ¿qué regresan los métodos en `$action`? ya que en los otros casos regresas json.

Comment: Si, le hice tail al error_log de apache, pero no pasa por esté.