# Enviando Datos POS al admin-ajax.php con Curl para Recibir un JSON

Tags: php, ajax, curl

Cuando envio esta URL
http://cinemaentucasa-1.ml/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=doo_player_ajax&post=2455&nume=1&type=movie
Recibo:
{
"embed_url": "",
"type": null
}
del server Origen estoy tratando de mediante Curl y POST simular este resultado pero me esta saliendo en Blanco.

```
<?php
function do_post($url, $JSONObj){

        $headers = array( 'Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                        'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9',
                        'Connection:keep-alive',
                        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
                        'Vary: Accept-Encoding',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://cinemaentucasa-1.ml',
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true',
                        'Origin: http://cinemaentucasa-1.ml',
                        'Host: cinemaentucasa-1.ml'
                        );

            $curl = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $JSONObj);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        $jsonResponse = curl_exec($curl);
            $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ( $status != 200 ) {
            die($status);
        }
        curl_close($curl);
        $response = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
    return $response;}  
$url='http://cinemaentucasa-1.ml/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
$json_var = [
            'action'=>'doo_player_ajax',
            'post'=>'2455',
            'nume'=>'1',
            'type'=>'movie',
];
print_r(do_post($url, $json_var));
?>
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/218426/822

Comment: NO entiendo que relacion tiene esa lectura con el tema de pasar info al Ajax.

Comment: Normal, ¿qué parte no se entiende?, por otro lado, ¿eres el sysadmin/webmaster de ese sitio web? De ser así, configuras el `.htaccess` los ejemplos están en las respuestas de esa pregunta, en caso no seas, creo que existe una alta probabilidad que no se pueda realizar lo que deseas, el motivo está en el enlace compartido anteriormente

Answer (score 0):

Encontre otra via para lograr la captura de la informacion. Pero a un haci estuve viendo otros ejemplos del uso del AJAX y con ninguno lo logre trasnferir la informacion.