# Problema con error CORS cuando hago un request a un URL pero no a otro aun cuando es exactamente el mismo código

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un error CORS que no entiendo para nada, espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

En el siguiente codigo, cuando el url es igual a url: `https://api.mercadolibre.com/questions/search?seller_id=123123123&sort_fields=date_created&sort_types=DESC`,

me da error CORS: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

pero cuando el url es igual a url: `https://api.mercadolibre.com/items?ids=MLC123321223`, el ajax funciona perfectamente.

```
$.ajax({
                //url: `https://api.mercadolibre.com/questions/search?seller_id=123123123&sort_fields=date_created&sort_types=DESC`,
                url: `https://api.mercadolibre.com/items?ids=MLC123321223`,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":  "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With",
                },
                type: 'GET',
            })
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: Bienvenidx a la comunidad de Stackoverflow. Por favor lee o visita de nuevo  [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recuerda que debes anteponer un título que describa bien el problema que tienes, así como resumir tu pregunta en los primeros párrafos, incluir (no pegar imágenes) del código que haga replicar el problema o donde creas que esté el problema, etc. El formular una buena pregunta, aumentará tus posibilidades de recibir ayuda por parte de la comunidad.