# Problemas con CORS

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, cors

Tengo un problema con las politicas CORS

Siempre que trato de ejecutar mi codigo me aparece un error de politicas CORS

Adjunto mi linea de codigo

```
<script>
// Enviando y recibiendo datos en formato JSON utilizando el método POST
//
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "API";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () 
{ 
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) 
{
var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
console.log(json.usuario + ", " + json.clave)
}
}

var data = JSON.stringify(
{
"username": "",
"password": ""
});
xhr.send(data);


</script>
```

Porfavor necesito de su ayuda

Porque a decir verdad

Eh colapsado

Y necesito terminar este proceso

Porfavor

Comment: El problem de CORS no lo puedes solucionar del lado cliente, debe ser del lado del Servidor.

Comment: Y como lo puedo solucionar del lado del servidor?

Comment: Tienes. Que. Revisar. La. Configuración. Del. Servidor. Porque. Nosotros. No. Vemos. En. Tu. Pregunta. Cómo. Está. Revisa si esto te sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin/220984#220984

Answer (score 0):

Los problemas de cors haciendo consultas desde un servidor local a otro se solucionan instalando en el navegador alguna extension para ignorar el control de cors, yo uso en chrome cors unblock o algo asi se llama y no tengo problema. Podes probar hacer la peticion desde postman que ignora los encabezados, si de esa forma te funciona bien lo solucionas como te digo.
Saludos

Comment: ¿Vas a pedirle a todos los usuarios que se instalen esa extensión? Por ahí no va la solución.

Comment: Esto es para desarrollo, cuando la aplicacion esta en el servidor haciendo peticiones con el front y el back dentro del mismo servidor no tenes este problema

Comment: Para desarrollo hay ambiente, por algo existe el CORS. Saludos.