# Error al hacer petición HTTP de manera local

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, http-get, xmlhttprequest

Al hacer la petición desde *https://www.w3schools.com* y desde cualquier página web todo funciona perfecto pero si la hago de manea local aparace: **Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en  (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'). Código de estado: 200.**

```js
$.ajax({

url: "www.example.com/html",
type: "GET",


success: function(h) {

document.write(h);

}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nos podrías dar información sobre tu entorno? Tienes algún back end que obtenga la llamada? es decir, lo que en tu ejemplo es "www.example.com/html" qué sería en realidad? Sería un servidor o página tuya o no?

Comment: Hay una pregunta similar a esta, que fue atendida con textos y soluciones en distintos lenguajes... Te dejo el enlace a esta pregunta [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 1):

le recomiendo este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin?rq=1)

Dan una explicación detallada de lo que te sucede y su solucción en un back-end php.

Para un back-end de nodejs en nestjs seria algo como esto:

```
 app.enableCors({
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
      if (!origin || whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
        // console.log('allowed cors for:', origin);
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
        console.log('blocked cors for:', origin);
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
      }
    },
    allowedHeaders:
      'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept, Observe, x-token, Set-Cookie',
    methods: 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,UPDATE,OPTIONS,PATCH',
    credentials: true,
  });
```

En express

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

`JQuery` se ejecuta en el navegador y, no existe tal cosa como establecer los encabezados allí usando tu código `JS`.

Si estas en modo laboratorio accediendo a [páginas de terceros](https://www.example.com/html) en tu entorno de desarrollo, y solo para realizar pruebas, lo mas facil es usar complementos para el navegador como [Allow Cors Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=es), [Allow Cors Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/access-control-allow-origin/), etc.

De otro modo, si quieres acceder a un servicio web este debe habilitar el **intercambio de recursos de origen cruzado** (Es lo que significa CORS), quizás esto te ayude a conseguirlo https://enable-cors.org/server.html. Luego en tu código `JS` quizas debas agregar `crossDomain: true` en la sentencia AJAX así:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "www.example.com/html",
  type: "GET",
  crossDomain: true, /* <-- set this attribute */
  success: function(h) {
    document.write(h);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS valida que el servidor de origen sea el mismo que el de destino, es un bloqueo que hacen los navegadores, para poder hacer la consulta te recomiendo que busques un plugin de chrome que se llama 'cors unblock', eso se activa y desactiva, cuando lo tenes activado ignora esta validacion de servidor origen-destino y vas a poder recuperar datos