# Como hacer una peticion get sin el que sea bloqueado por Cors policy usando Javascript y node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, cors, http-get

Estoy aprendiendo node.js e hice un servidor que recibe una petición get, pero es bloqueada por Cors policy. Estoy trabajando con express y axios.
Agredezco mucho su ayuda.

Agrego mi código a continuación:

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const puerto = 5555
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getData)
        async function getData() {
            let res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:${puerto}/jugadores`)
            json = await res.data;
            console.log(json)
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
servidor.js

const express = require('express')
const { jugadores } = require('./base-datos')
const app = express()

app.get('/jugadores',(req, res)=>{
    res.send(jugadores)
})
puerto = 5555
app.listen(puerto, () => {
    console.log(`Puerto ${puerto}. Escuchando ...`)
});
```

```
base-datos.js

let jugadores = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "Jugador1"

    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nombre": "Jugador2"

    }

]

module.exports.jugadores = jugadores
```

Y estos son los errores que me marca en consola:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5555/jugadores' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

> Uncaught (in promise) ocode: "ERR_NETWORK"config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}message: "Network Error"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest {data: undefined, onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, …}response: XMLHttpRequest {data: undefined, onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, …}[[Prototype]]: Error

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/220984/822 Saludos.

Comment: Parece que estás intentando hacer la peticion al servidor desde un archivo abierto localmente. Debes agregar la línea `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` antes de devolver los jugadores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lo que veo, tu `index.html` y tu `servidor.js` no están conectados de ninguna manera. Es decir, tu servidor no está, literalmente, **sirviendo** el `index.html` entonces no lo entiende como suyo por ende bloquea la petición.

Hay varias maneras de resolver este issue:

1. delegándole al servidor que **sirva** el `index.html` es decir, que solo se pueda acceder a ese archivo por medio del servidor.
2. setear manualmente el `header`:`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` en el response.
3. que le digas a tu servidor explícitamente que acepte los requests de cualquier origen o darle una lista detallada de origenes permitidos.

### Solución uno.

Tendrás que servir `index.html` desde `servidor.js`:

```js
const { jugadores } = require('./base-datos')
const app = express()

// esta ruta es nueva  y sirve el index.html
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

app.get('/jugadores', (req, res) => {
  res.json(jugadores)
})

app.listen(5555, () => console.log('Server started on port 5555'))
```

Ahora debes visitar `http://localhost:5555/` y al abrir la consola verás que tus `jugadores` se están trayendo de la base de datos.

#### Por qué funciona?

Porque el servidor entiende que la petición se está originando en el **mismo origen** es decir `http://localhost:5555`.

### Solución dos.

Agrega el `header`:`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` manualmente:

```js
const express = require('express')
const { jugadores } = require('./base-datos')
const app = express()

app.get('/jugadores',(req, res)=>{
    // esta línea permite a esta ruta en específico ser fetcheada desde cualquier origen
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.send(jugadores)
})
puerto = 5555
app.listen(puerto, () => {
    console.log(`Puerto ${puerto}. Escuchando ...`)
});
```

### Solución tres.

Agrega [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) a tu servidor.

```js
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const { jugadores } = require('./base-datos')
const app = express()

// con este línea  tu servidor acepta requests de cualquier origen
app.use(cors())

app.get('/jugadores',(req, res)=>{
    res.send(jugadores)
})
puerto = 5555
app.listen(puerto, () => {
    console.log(`Puerto ${puerto}. Escuchando ...`)
});
```

#### Por qué funciona?

El método [`.use()`](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) ejecuta *middlewares* (un middleware es simplemente una función que puede modificar el `request` y el `response` de una petición antes que dicha petición sea ejecutada en la ruta deseada). En este caso, el *middleware* que estamos usando es `cors()` que modifica el objeto `response` del servidor que permite el accesso al servidor por medio del `header`:`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

##### Estas son algunas lecturas que te podrían interesar para entender más sobre el tema:

- [Control de acceso HTTP (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
- [CORS and the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cors/access-control-allow-origin#:%7E:text=What%20is%20the%20Access%2DControl,permitted%20origin%20of%20the%20request.)

Comment: @AmilcharMunoz  Tu respuesta me fue muy útil en un principio, pero ahora veo que mucha veces funciona aun sin agregar ni una de las soluciones que me diste. Y en ocasiones tampoco funcionan las soluciones dadas. Por qué esta pasando esto? Agradecería mucho tu ayuda!

Comment: @ZCH sin ver el código, no podría decirte qué está mal. Crea otra pregunta donde expliques tu nueva situación.