# Error javascript y api propia creada en flask

Tags: javascript, api, flask, flask-restful

cree una api propia que devuelve un arreglo de acores musicales, esta creada en flask

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/api/v1/<int:transponer>/<int:gradoinicial>")
@app.route("/api/v1/<int:transponer>")
@app.route("/api/v1")
def action(transponer = 0, gradoinicial = 0):
    return jsonify(CrearProgresionJson(transponer,gradoinicial))
app.run(debug=True)
```

cuando entro desde mi navegador me muestra sin problemas el objeto JSON en este formato

```
{
"Acordes": [
[
"C#4",
"C#5",
"E5",
"G#5",
"B5"
],
[
"F#4",
"F#5",
"A5",
"C#5",
"E5"
],
[
"C#4",
"C#5",
"E5",
"G#5",
"B5"
],
[
"A3",
"A5",
"C#5",
"E5",
"G#5",
"B5"
]
],
"Grados": [
"Im7",
"IVm7",
"Im7",
"VIM9"
]
}
```

sin embargo cuando intento desde JS hacer un fetch me da un error en la consola;
**Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/1/1' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**

Aqui el html:

```
<body>
    <script>
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/1/1')
        
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json))

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Debes configurar en el backend, es decir habilitar tus `CORS` para que puedan utilizar tus métodos desde cualquier parte. Para verificar que funciona todo bien puedes usar `Postman` o si usas `visual studio code` instalate el `thunder client`. Con esas herramientas puedes verificar que los puntos de api estan bien. De ser asi verifica como habilitar las CORS en el back. Saludos

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/220984/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es importante entender que son los CORS y por qué da el problema. En [este artículo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) puedes entender un poco mejor que es un elemento de seguridad de principalmente de los navegadores para evitar peticiones de puertos o servidores diferentes al principal.

Entendiendo esto, puedes ver que en flash existe una manera sencilla de manejarlos con la extensión de [Flask Cors](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Esta extensión simplemente introduces tu punto de acceso y añades los dominios-puertos que habilitas para hacer peticiones, en caso de que no quieras restringirlo simplemente puedes habilitarlo para todos

```
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```