# Buenas tardes , si alguien pudiera indicarme el error que no veo y me estoy volviendo loco ejj

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

```
const options = {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        mode: 'no-cors'
    };
    
    fetch("https://api.dstudio.io/kinetic/integration?fechaAlta=2022-06-01", options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {console.log(data)})
        .catch(err => console.error(err))***
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de consumir una api pero ni modo,
Ahí muestro el error, si pudieran ayudarme, gracias

Comment: Simple... ¿Tienes habilitado el dominio/IP para que la API funcione? Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/220984/822 Saludos.

Comment: ¿has mirado la consola cuando haces esa petición?  Diria que tienes un problema CORS y allí se mostrará el error seguramente

Comment: No no, no tengo el dominio, ahí miro gracias

Comment: en principio tenia problemas con CORS, pero luego de agregar el headers y mode no me mostró más error que el que muestro