# Error de Cors en Proyecto generado por Vite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

he estado realizando una aplicación con vue con la herramienta vite, y justo ahora estoy haciendo el `npm run build` para generar la aplicación, se genera correctamente, sin saltarme ningún error, pero al momento de abrir el index.html, la consola del navegador me indica los siguientes errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado en infinidad de foros una solución, pero no he llegado a una concreta, si alguien me puede ayudar, se los agradecería

Comment: El error de CORS se produce cuando se intenta realizar una solicitud HTTP desde un origen que no coincide con el origen del recurso al que se está intentando acceder. Esto se debe a una política de seguridad implementada por la mayoría de los navegadores web para evitar que las aplicaciones web malintencionadas accedan a recursos alojados en servidores externos sin permiso. Para solucionar este problema, hay varias opciones. Una de ellas es configurar el servidor web del recurso al que se intenta acceder para que incluya el encabezado de respuesta Access-Control-Allow-Origin con el origen perm

Comment: Lecturas altamente sugeridas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/220984/822 + https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour (aquí te informas sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtienes tu primera medalla) + https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.