# Error "falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'). Código de estado: 200" al realizar una petición AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, servidor, peticion

estoy intentando hacer una petición AJAX desde una web hacia un servidor y me salta este error "Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en mi_url_del_servidor (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'). Código de estado: 200.". La pregunta es si hay alguna manera de evitar que te salte dicho error con una petición AJAX o si hay otro método que se pueda utilizar en su lugar. Gracias de antemano.

Petición AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "get",
    DataType: "text",
    data: {"mensaje": "hola"},
    success: function(respuesta) {
        console.log("Entra en la respuesta");
        console.log(respuesta);
    }
});
```

Comment: Tienes acceso al servidor?

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso al ocdigo del servidor ?

Comment: Esto principalmente se da cuando desde un servidor no conocido por tu Backend intenta acceder a la información. Con los CORS los navegadores realizar una solicitud al servidor que aloja los datos con el fin de comprobar que el servidor permitirá la solicitud real. Por eso se te pregunta si tienes acceso al código del servidor ya que normalmente eso se soluciona por decirlo así "desde adentro".

Comment: Muchas gracias amigos, lo solucioné indicando desde donde venia la petición e indicando que método era el utilizado para enviar la petición. Para ello utilicé estas dos líneas de código. header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: el origen de la petición"); y header("Access-Control-Request-Method: POST");. Encontré la información aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin#comment406471_218426