# Porque me bloquea CORS en python?

Tags: python, api, rest, flask, cors

Tengo una Api REST en python en un servidor con XAMPP, no habia tenido problemas al usarlo, ya que importe el flask_cors y lo llame a mi instancia.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

Pero al querer acceder desde otra lap a travez de la IP, al hacer peticiones me marca error:

*Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada:
La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en http://127.0.0.1:5000/login. (Razón: Solicitud CORS sin éxito). Código de estado: (null).*

Algo curioso es que ayer si funcionaba pero hoy ya no.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: Creo que se necesita un poco mas de info + codigo para que te puedan echar una mano, pueden haber varios factores porque la politica de CORS te de problemas, si ayer te funciono puede ser que lo hayas probado con http://localhost:5000/login y CORS lo permite, pero sin mas codigo y info poco puedo ayudarte.