# Problemas en el CORS

Tags: javascript, html, cors, webapi

tengo una WEB API con .NET 6, al hacer mi trabajo en postman me funciona de maravilla, tengo mi proyecto solo con HTML y JS en el localhost y al tratar de consumir la WEB API, me sale este error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:7265/api/Roles/Listar' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

la cuestion es que la URL que genera la WEB API si funciona bien, inclusive si ingreso directamente desde el navegador con el que corro mi proyecto, tambien abre sin problema alguno

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo del js con el que estoy tratando de consumir la Web API

```
function listarroles(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://localhost:7265/api/Roles/Listar",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result)
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log('Error: '+error);
        }
    });
};
```

la verdad he consultado y todo pero no encuentro la solución, solo veo, usa esta linea de require('cors'), pero no muestran donde debe instalarse, busque un codigo y no me deja instalar ese paquete de cors en mi proyecto (ingrese al terminal en la carpeta raiz de mi proyecto y use npm i cors pero nada).

Agradezco mucho su ayuda

Este es el appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MySQLConnection": "server=localhost;port=3306;database=mangoo;uid=root;password=123456789"
  }
}
```

y este es el program.cs

```
using API_Mangoo.Data;
using API_Mangoo.Data.Repositorios;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var mySQLConfiguration = new MySQLConfiguration(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySQLConnection"));
builder.Services.AddSingleton(mySQLConfiguration);
//builder.Services.AddSingleton(new MySqlConnection(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySQLConnection")));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRolesRepositorio, RolesRepositorio>();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

estuve consultando, instale NodeJS y empece a usarlo, pero ahora el problema radica en otra cosa jajajaja

ya quedaron las librerias instaladas, se creo el package-lock.json y el package.json

pero al momento de colocar estas lineas

```
function listarroles(){
    console.log('iniciando proceso de listar los roles');
    const express = require('express');
    const cors = require('cors');

    const app = express();

    app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://localhost:8080',
    methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With'
    }));

    $('#tbodyrolessH').empty();
    $('#tablarolesV').empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost:7265/api/Roles/Listar",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error)
            console.log(status)
        }
    });
};
```

y me sale esto

```
jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at listarroles (<anonymous>:148:21)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:2:5)
```

Comment: eso iria en la peticion ajax cierto?

Comment: Si usas Node, debes dar permiso a `localhost:7265` en el archivo de configuración, para que no te bloquee las peticiones que van dirigidas a esa URL. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/218428/29967). Ante estos casos, la solución simple es sugerir que des permiso a todo, pero no hagas eso, CORS existe para dar seguridad a tu sitio una vez esté en producción, por ejemplo, mediante CORS puedes indicar qué dominios o qué archivos específicos tienen permiso para ejecutarse en tu sitio, lo cual aumenta enormemente la seguridad, bloqueando potenciales archivos extraños.

Comment: Como te comentan, esa cabecera es restringida desde el lado cliente, debes añadirla como parte de las cabeceras de respuesta del servidor. Durante desarrollo, lo usual es permitir conexiones desde cualquier origen mediante la cabecera de respuesta: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: Los que cerraron la pregunta por duplicada, podrian señalar cual de las 6 respuesta aplica a este caso que se ocupa .net 6??

Comment: no estoy usando Node, por ende no tengo el archivo de configuracion

Comment: la otra situacion es que no puedo usar php, y para eso segun la consulta debo usar express, no se si estoy buscando de la forma correcta o no

Comment: tengo el ajax de esta forma, ya no me sale el problema del error

Comment: $.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost:7265/api/Roles/Listar",
        type: 'GET',
        accepts: "application/json",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result)
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log('Error: '+error);
        }
    });

Comment: Creo que debería reabrirse esta pregunta.

Comment: @Yussef porque no tienen ni idea??? :p

Comment: Por favor, agrega en tu pregunta el main de tu program.cs para ver donde hay que agregar CORS. tu api tiene que aceptar peticiones desde esa URL para que sea valido.

Comment: y espera a que reabran tu pregunta para que te puedan dar una respuesta, o indicarte la duplicada correcta...

Comment: En el archivo appsettings.json agrega la siguiente configuración "AllowedHosts": "*"

Comment: ya agregue en la pregunta el appsettings.json y el program.cs

Comment: ya revisaste esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74344518/cors-missing-allow-origin-error-net-core-api-when-trying-to-fetch-data)?, ahí se ve desde las herramientas de desarrollo que regresa el navegador, podrías adjuntar eso a la pregunta?

Comment: No tienen idea? Seguro? Es exactamente el mismo principio: Añadir un paquete de CORS (de Microsoft y no de NPM) configurar el servicio (`builder.services.AddCors( ... )`) y por último usarlo (`app.UseCors( ... )`). Pero ¿qué sabremos nosotros de CORS si la pregunta es `.Net` y no de `javascript`? `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Pero en la redacción de la pregunta sí dices que usas Node: *ingrese al terminal en la carpeta raiz de mi proyecto y use npm i cors pero nada*, en realidad `npm` es el manejador de paquetes de **Node**, o sea, que estás usando Node, aunque no seas consciente de ello.

Comment: @A.Cedano no esta usando node, OP no tenia ni idea como resolverlo e instalo CORS en el front...

Comment: @FrancescoVirgolini obviamente no, porque ya fue marcada por eso, y porque ninguna de las respuestas es de c#....

Comment: acomode el ajax con el headers $.ajax({ url: "localhost:7265/api/Roles/Listar", dataType: "jsonp", type: 'GET', contentType: "application/json", crossDomain: true, mode: 'cors', headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }, success: function (result) { console.log(result) }, error: function(error){ console.log('Error: '+error); } }); pero ahora me sale este error en consola

Error: [object Object]

Comment: ya estoy usando el node js pero me sale ahora el error require is not defined at listarroles, actualice el codigo en la pregunta

Comment: Bueno, no terminamos de aclararnos con este problema. ¿Podrías decirnos lo que vas a usar del lado del servidor? La configuración de CORS dependerá de eso.

Comment: del lado del servidor? en el servidor solo hay una base de datos mysql y una web api en .NEt6 y pues el proyecto en html y js

Comment: Pues configura CORS en el entorno de. NET. [Revisa la documentación al respecto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que debes entender es que el bloqueo de CORS lo realiza el **NAVEGADOR**, al saber esto ya puedes suponer que:

- Desde javascript no hay nada que puedas hacer para solucionarlo
- Cuando no ocupas el navegador no tendrás problemas (por ejemplo desde Postman o desde el servidor)

Para permitir solicitudes de origines distintos el servidor debe setear la cabecera de la respuesta correctamente, así el navegador las permitirá.

En .net es posible realizarlo de muchas formas, puede permitir a una lista de subdominios, a ciertos *method*  (get, post, put, etc) o a `endpoints` particulares. En la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0) hay varios ejemplos.

Para permitir todos los origenes, un `program.cs` debería verse así:

```
using API_Mangoo.Data;
using API_Mangoo.Data.Repositorios;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var mySQLConfiguration = new MySQLConfiguration(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySQLConnection"));
builder.Services.AddSingleton(mySQLConfiguration);
//builder.Services.AddSingleton(new MySqlConnection(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySQLConnection")));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRolesRepositorio, RolesRepositorio>();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "origenes", //nombre de la politica
                        policy =>
                        {
                            policy.WithOrigins("*"); //cualquier origen
                        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors("origenes"); //usamos el mismo nombre de arriba


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Yussef, esas lineas si funcionaron y la verdad si, intente muchas veces hacerlo desde js y no funcionaba de ninguna forma, te agradezco demasiado

Comment: policy.WithHeaders("*");

Comment: toca cambir agregar este policy porque con ese codigo igual solo permite GET, toca agregar esta otra para permitir varias funciones