# Problema al realizar una petición AJAX con jQuery y obtener un error de CORS

Tags: javascript

¡Hola comunidad de Stack Overflow!

Estoy experimentando dificultades al intentar realizar una petición AJAX con jQuery en mi aplicación web y me preguntaba si alguien podría orientarme en la resolución de este problema. Agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme.
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web en la que necesito realizar una solicitud AJAX a un servidor externo para obtener datos. Estoy utilizando jQuery para simplificar el proceso, pero al hacer la petición, me encuentro con un error de CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) que no he logrado superar.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://api.servidorexterno.com/datos',
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
    // Procesar los datos recibidos
},
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    console.error('Error en la petición AJAX:', status, error);
}
```

});

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/218426/falta-la-cabecera-cors-access-control-allow-origin)