# CORS en entorno de desarrollo Docker + Expo react native

Tags: react-native, docker, symfony, cors

Llevo varios días intentando solucionar el siguiente problema en un entorno de desarrollo local. Tengo montado lo siguiente:

- Proyecto 1: Contenedor docker con una API creada en `symfony` que escucha en el puerto 8080.
- Proyecto 2: App `react native` en expo que escucha en el puerto 8081 y que necesita beber de esa API.

No quiero `dockerizar` el proyecto de react native porque directamente lo subiré a producción mediante el servicio EAS de Expo.

Cuando llamo desde el Proyecto 2 al Proyecto 1 a través de un Endpoint desde el navegador aparece el mensaje de las `CORS`.

> "Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en http://localhost:8080/api/login (razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'). Código de estado: 405."

He modificado el archivo `/etc/hosts` para redirigir `localhost` a un subdominio ficticio y he probado desde ahí pero nada.

He usado `Ngrok` para crear una url externa de la API y llamar desde `localhost:8081` del Proyecto 2 a esa url pero nada.

He probado alguna extensión del navegador para intentar deshabilitar las `CORS` y nada.

No sé me ocurre ahora mismo nada más que hacer.

Comment: CORS se habilita desde la API. Por otro lado, en el buscador de arriba escribe ""CORS" y hay una buena cantidad de opciones para leer, la más recomendada es: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/218426/822